# Slow boot issue due to plymouth-quit-wait.service + ubuntu 18.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 18.04, systemd, plymouth

This is freshly installed machine running as dual boot over Win 10. 
For every reboot machine hangs for 15 secs as the plymouth service unable to start, due to some reasons.

ENv:-

```
    Manufacturer: Dell Inc.
    Product Name: Precision 5820 Tower
    Ubuntu 18.04 
    4.15.0-29-generic 
    vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
    model    : GP104GL [Quadro P4000]
```

Below is the systemd-analyse output snippet

```
sudo systemd-analyze blame
     14.405s plymouth-quit-wait.service
      8.843s dev-sdb4.device
      8.049s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
      5.305s bolt.service
      4.889s snapd.service
      4.243s udisks2.service
      4.092s grub-common.service
      3.806s networking.service
      3.780s ModemManager.service
      3.325s dev-loop10.device
      3.295s apparmor.service
      3.190s dev-loop13.device
      3.162s accounts-daemon.service
```

Here is the few snippet of boot logs

```
Feb 18 11:37:42  polkitd[876]: started daemon version 0.105 using 
authority implementation `local' version `0.105'
Feb 18 11:37:42  dbus-daemon[820]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1'
Feb 18 11:37:42 systemd[1]: Started Authorization Manager.
Feb 18 11:37:42  accounts-daemon[801]: started daemon version 0.6.45
Feb 18 11:37:42  systemd[1]: Started Accounts Service.
Feb 18 11:37:42  systemd[1]: Received SIGRTMIN+20 from PID 394 (plymouthd).
```

Here is the delay

```
 Feb 18 11:37:57  nvidia-persistenced: The daemon no longer has 
 permission to remove its runtime data directory /var/run/nvidia- 
 persistenced
 Feb 18 11:37:57  nvidia-persistenced: Shutdown (1206)
 Feb 18 11:37:57  systemd[1]: Stopped NVIDIA Persistence Daemon.
 Feb 18 11:37:58  gdm3: Child process -1088 was already dead.
 Feb 18 11:37:58  systemd[1]: Stopping User Manager for UID 121...
 Feb 18 11:37:58 systemd[1]: Received SIGRTMIN+21 from PID 394 (plymouthd)

sudo systemctl status plymouth-quit-wait.service
● plymouth-quit-wait.service - Hold until boot process finishes up
 Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/plymouth-quit-wait.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
 Active: inactive (dead) since Mon 2019-02-18 11:37:58 +04; 7min ago
Main PID: 943 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Feb 18 11:37:43  systemd[1]: Starting Hold until boot 
process finishes up...
Feb 18 11:37:58  systemd[1]: Started Hold until boot 
process finishes up.
```

Graphics driver installed latest version - 415 from ppa repository

```
ii  nvidia-compute-utils-415                   415.27-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.2          amd64        NVIDIA compute utilities
ii  nvidia-dkms-415                            415.27-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.2          amd64        NVIDIA DKMS package
ii  nvidia-driver-415                          415.27-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.2          amd64        NVIDIA driver metapackage
ii  nvidia-kernel-common-415                   415.27-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.2          amd64        Shared files used with the kernel module
ii  nvidia-kernel-source-415                   415.27-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.2          amd64        NVIDIA kernel source package
ii  nvidia-prime                               0.8.8.2                             all          Tools to enable NVIDIA's Prime
ii  nvidia-settings                            415.27-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1          amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
ii  nvidia-utils-415                           415.27-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.2          amd64        NVIDIA driver support binaries
ii  xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-415              415.27-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.2          amd64        NVIDIA binary Xorg driver
```

Can you let me know why there is a delay happening due to plymount-quit service? Please let me know is there any other info you would require for troubleshoot?

Is it related to hardware / software /grahics driver issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 58):

**Plymouth is not slowing your boot-up process!** Plymouth is responsible for the boot-up splash screen. Please read [Plymouth](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Plymouth).

It loads the boot-up logo at the beginning of the boot-up process and then **waits** until the boot-up process has finished so it unloads the splash screen. That is **all** it does and that is why it has to run in parallel and co-exist throughout the **whole** boot-up process. It does not delay anything, it just **waits**.

That is exactly what is happening. **No more and no less**. Please take a look at the output you added to [your question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1119167/968501) and carefully read the following:

> ● plymouth-quit-wait.service - **Hold until boot process finishes up**

---

## How to Verify?

You can verify that `plymouth-quit-wait.service` is not holding anything back but the graphical login screen, by running the command:

```
systemctl list-dependencies --reverse plymouth-quit-wait.service
```

which will output all the services that depend on `plymouth-quit-wait.service` (i.e services that are delayed by `plymouth-quit-wait.service`). On a freshly installed Ubuntu system, the output will be like this:

```
plymouth-quit-wait.service
● └─multi-user.target
●   └─graphical.target
```

Which means only the **graphical login screen** is configured to wait for the `plymouth-quit-wait.service` and **nothing else**.

On the other hand if you list the services that `plymouth-quit-wait.service` is configured to wait for by running the command:

```
systemctl list-dependencies plymouth-quit-wait.service
```

the output would be almost every service that should run on boot and the output will look like this:

```
plymouth-quit-wait.service
● ├─system.slice
● └─sysinit.target
●   ├─apparmor.service
●   ├─dev-hugepages.mount
●   ├─dev-mqueue.mount
●   ├─grub-initrd-fallback.service
●   ├─keyboard-setup.service
●   ├─kmod-static-nodes.service
●   ├─plymouth-read-write.service
●   ├─plymouth-start.service
●   ├─proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.automount
●   ├─setvtrgb.service
●   ├─sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
●   ├─sys-kernel-config.mount
●   ├─sys-kernel-debug.mount
●   ├─systemd-ask-password-console.path
●   ├─systemd-binfmt.service
●   ├─systemd-hwdb-update.service
●   ├─systemd-journal-flush.service
●   ├─systemd-journald.service
●   ├─systemd-machine-id-commit.service
●   ├─systemd-modules-load.service
●   ├─systemd-random-seed.service
●   ├─systemd-sysctl.service
●   ├─systemd-sysusers.service
●   ├─systemd-timesyncd.service
●   ├─systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
●   ├─systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
●   ├─systemd-udev-trigger.service
●   ├─systemd-udevd.service
●   ├─systemd-update-utmp.service
●   ├─cryptsetup.target
●   ├─local-fs.target
●   │ ├─-.mount
●   │ ├─systemd-fsck-root.service
●   │ └─systemd-remount-fs.service
●   └─swap.target
●     └─swapfile.swap
```

This confirms that `plymouth-quit-wait.service` is not slowing down anything but just running in parallel waiting for the system to fully boot and then it will hide the boot-up splash screen to bring up the graphical login screen.

---

**To understand more.**

Please run the following command in the terminal:

```
systemd-analyze plot > ~/SystemdAnalyzePlot.svg
```

Then, look for `SystemdAnalyzePlot.svg` in your home directory and run it in the *image viewer* or the *Internet browser*. You might need to enlarge the image so that you can read the processes names. It is worth checking and will give you a better understanding on how the boot-up process works.

---

You can, however, **reduce your boot-up time** by disabling `NetworkManager-wait-online.service` so **plymouth** has one less process to wait for. This can indeed reduce your boot-up time. To do this please follow the steps in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1166492/968501).

---

Oh... and please leave plymouth alone, it's not the one that makes you wait...it's the one that waits for you.

Comment: What is the purpose of `NetworkManager-wait-online` service? Need to know what could go wrong I disable this service

Comment: @GovindaSakhare The purpose of the `NetworkManager-wait-online.service` is to wait for the network to come on-line before proceeding with the boot process. This is needed in case of for example servers that rely on network resources as part of the boot process ( eg. mounting remote drives ) or in the case of workstations that rely on the network to boot correctly ( eg. Thin Clients ). Otherwise, desktop users can disable `NetworkManager-wait-online.service` and network will connect normally after boot has finished minus the unneeded wait time. It is safe to disable in this case.

Comment: I'm willing to believe it's /supposed/ to work as you say but on one of my machines the plot shows "plymouth-quit-wait.service (5min 39.552s)" and it would show longer except that I logged in via ssh and killed plymouth. About six other services seem to be waiting for plymouth to quit. The plot does not seem to indicate that plymouth is waiting for something specific. How can I find it?

Comment: @aap I have just updated the answer to address your concern. Thank you

Comment: @Raffa Then why does my machine boot in mere seconds when I remove "splash" from the kernel command line in /etc/default/grub?

Comment: @aap The procedure described in your comment will not disable plymouth. It will still run as usual but will not display a splash screen. In fact this proves that plymouth is not responsible for the previous delay as it is still running anyway. What the procedure described in your comment might indeed solve is a miss-configured  plymouth theme and this is a totally different issue which you can post in a new question to get the proper solution for it. Best regards

Comment: @Raffa I am sorry, but your reply sort-of makes me a bit angry. Why? I have GitLab-CE running on my Ubuntu 18.04.0x LTS and for the heck of it I could not get it work... until I found about `sudo systemctl list-jobs`. Guess what was waiting the not letting `gitlab-runsvdir` continue? Right. `plymouth-quit-wait.service`. So after killing it using `sudo killall plymouth` that `gitlab-runsvdir` suddenly continued starting... I did not do anything before that except installing GitLab a long while ago. After the recent updates (up to 2 months) GitLab just stopped working. Now it works again.

Comment: @Igor That is a totally different matter and what you did is just a temporary work-arond and not the solution. I would investigate why `gitlab-runsvdir` behaves this way and fix `gitlab-runsvdir` not kill `plymouth`. The reason might be that  `gitlab-runsvdir` depends on `multi-user.target` and needs to be configured to run after it or the status of `gitlab-runsvdir` might not be reported correctly and need to be fixed or some other reason. Please, do not get angry and post a new question instead with this information so that you get help fixing this `gitlab-runsvdir` issue. :) smile please.

Comment: I restarted the server several times because of updates - and it still works just fine. So while perhaps this might be temporarily, it works. I have no means to investigate gitlab-runsvdir, because I wouldn't understand it anyway. Thank you for your reply though :).

Comment: I don't know I used to have the same problem, but disabling plymouth DID reduce my bootup time. Is there an explanation to this?

Comment: I was having the same problem, but sometimes the boot will be faster and sometimes slower.I believe it is related to network-online.target and other network services waiting for network and hence Plymouth also showing more time. I am not bothered about it anymore, since i understand why this is happening based on answer from faffa

Answer (score 8):

I cannot say what else is necessary, but I can maybe give a workaround for you, so that the machine starts faster.

For me the most working solution was to disable the plymouth in grub with

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

and change the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` into

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="noplymouth video=SVIDEO-1:d"
```

After saving the change you must update the grub with

```
sudo update-grub
```

and then restart the machine.

Answer (score -2):

You can disable this service by running the command :

```
sudo systemctl disable plymouth-quit-wait.service
```

From Service Description:

> Hold until boot process finishes up

Comment: Some explanation, maybe?

Comment: Disabling `plymouth-quit-wait.service` is not going to help. Please see my answer here. Thank you

Answer (score -2):

I was having boot time as 3-4 minutes because of this plymouth service taking 1 minute 30 seconds. What fixed my boot time was updating the kernel from 5.4(my default) to 5.9 in Ubuntu 20.

[update your kernel](https://linuxhint.com/update_ubuntu_kernel_20_04/)

Comment: As the other answers mention, the plymouth-quit-wait.service it not "the issue". The issue may be anything else, but installing an unsupported kernel may not be a good answer to everyone.