# Slow booting in Ubuntu 19.04 with full disk encryption

Tags: boot, uefi, encryption, asus, performance

I have an 960GB SSD ([Kingston A400](https://www.kingston.com/us/ssd/a400-solid-state-drive)) installed on my laptop ([Asus X505BA](https://www.asus.com/us/Laptops/ASUS-VivoBook-15-X505BA/specifications/)). I installed Ubuntu 19.04 with full disk encryption. I also have enabled fast boot and secure boot in the UEFI settings. My problem is that the system decryption at boot is really slow. It usually takes 4 to 5 minutes, too much compared with the booting time I used to have with a non encrypted HDD in the same laptop (usually 1 minute or less).

What can I do to improve this?

Update: Here is the systemd-analyze blame log.

```
      9.914s plymouth-quit-wait.service
      8.035s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
      5.181s fstrim.service
      3.172s snapd.service
      2.787s vboxdrv.service
      2.488s dev-mapper-ubuntu\x2d\x2dvg\x2droot.device
      1.997s systemd-logind.service
      1.934s vmware.service
      1.717s networkd-dispatcher.service
      1.472s udisks2.service
      1.461s dev-loop8.device
      1.408s dev-loop9.device
      1.402s dev-loop10.device
      1.398s dev-loop13.device
      1.394s motd-news.service
      1.378s dev-loop12.device
      1.372s dev-loop11.device
      1.119s vmware-USBArbitrator.service
      1.077s dev-loop1.device
      1.076s dev-loop2.device
      1.072s dev-loop0.device
      1.072s vmware-workstation-server.service
      1.059s dev-loop3.device
      1.025s dev-loop4.device
       992ms dev-loop5.device
       989ms dev-loop6.device
       954ms fwupd.service
       953ms dev-loop7.device
       768ms ModemManager.service
       688ms NetworkManager.service
       681ms accounts-daemon.service
       655ms systemd-journald.service
       652ms winbind.service
       635ms systemd-timesyncd.service
       623ms upower.service
       537ms avahi-daemon.service
       537ms bluetooth.service
       534ms ufw.service
       533ms systemd-resolved.service
       524ms tlp.service
       496ms user@1000.service
       493ms wpa_supplicant.service
       493ms apparmor.service
       467ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
       377ms swapfile.swap
       353ms gpu-manager.service
       346ms lm-sensors.service
       331ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1198.mount
       297ms keyboard-setup.service
       296ms rsyslog.service
       281ms switcheroo-control.service
       277ms snap-gnome\x2dcharacters-296.mount
       276ms snap-core-7396.mount
       270ms snap-gnome\x2dsystem\x2dmonitor-77.mount
       259ms grub-common.service
       259ms atd.service
       254ms gdm.service
       249ms systemd-udevd.service
       242ms thermald.service
       240ms pppd-dns.service
       234ms snap-gnome\x2dlogs-61.mount
       230ms ecbd.service
       228ms apport.service
       217ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d28\x2d1804-31.mount
       210ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1313.mount
       209ms snap-core18-1074.mount
       205ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d28\x2d1804-71.mount
       197ms snap-gnome\x2dcalculator-406.mount
       194ms hddtemp.service
       192ms snap-gnome\x2dsystem\x2dmonitor-100.mount
       191ms systemd-journal-flush.service
       184ms snap-core-6673.mount
       177ms snap-core18-941.mount
       176ms teamviewerd.service
       173ms snap-gnome\x2dcharacters-254.mount
       172ms colord.service
       151ms lvm2-monitor.service
       146ms networking.service
```

Comment: Please post output of `systemd-analyze blame`.

Comment: systemd-analyze blame output posted.

Comment: First entry on the list You can just disable by `sudo systemctl disable plymouth-quit-wait.service` - see if this resolves Your issue.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/q/1166486/968501 and https://askubuntu.com/q/1119167/968501