# Fix slow boot on Ubuntu Desktop 18.04

Tags: boot, 18.04, services

It's been a few days since I've installed Ubuntu for the first time and the boot time is quite slow. I read many threads about it and tried different ways to solve the problem but nothing worked, I improved the boot time only by a few seconds.

I already reduced the time configuration in `/etc/systemd/system.conf` and uninstalled all the apps I don't use but nothing changed.

This is what I get with `systemd-analyze`

`Startup finished in 7.504s (kernel) + 1min 5.807s (userspace) = 1min 13.312s
graphical.target reached after 1min 5.083s in userspace`

then, `systemd-analyze blame`

```
     31.467s plymouth-quit-wait.service
     22.757s dev-sda1.device
     16.636s snapd.service
     15.032s networkd-dispatcher.service
     12.792s apparmor.service
     12.510s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
     10.454s dev-loop1.device
     10.395s systemd-journal-flush.service
     10.330s dev-loop6.device
     10.271s dev-loop2.device
     10.262s dev-loop4.device
      9.820s dev-loop7.device
      9.571s NetworkManager.service
      9.335s dev-loop0.device
      9.247s dev-loop5.device
      8.671s dev-loop3.device
      8.161s accounts-daemon.service
      7.885s ModemManager.service
      7.416s grub-common.service
      5.546s udisks2.service
      4.756s systemd-logind.service
      4.715s pppd-dns.service
      3.504s thermald.service
```

lastly, `systemd-analyze critical-chain`

`The time after the unit is active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit takes to start is printed after the "+" character.
graphical.target @1min 5.083s
└─multi-user.target @1min 5.082s
  └─kerneloops.service @46.043s +107ms
    └─network-online.target @46.030s
      └─NetworkManager-wait-online.service @33.511s +12.510s
        └─NetworkManager.service @23.911s +9.571s
          └─dbus.service @19.906s
            └─basic.target @19.810s
              └─sockets.target @19.809s
                └─snapd.socket @19.707s +101ms
                  └─sysinit.target @19.691s
                    └─apparmor.service @6.897s +12.792s
                      └─local-fs.target @6.785s
                        └─run-user-121.mount @40.677s
                          └─local-fs-pre.target @6.241s
                            └─keyboard-setup.service @4.392s +1.848s
                              └─systemd-journald.socket @4.231s
                                └─system.slice @4.227s
                                  └─-.slice @4.177s`

Could I disable any of the following services or would it be too dangerous?:
`plymouth-quit-wait.service`
`dev-sda1.device`
`snapd.service`
`networkd-dispatcher.service`

Comment: I do not know about plymouth, but for sure sda1 is your hard drive, snapd is to allow you to run software, and networkd is to allow you to have a network. So I would imagine that the answer is easy for those.

Comment: @alexiswilke so there’s nothing i can do? thanks and happy new year!

Comment: 22 seconds (30%) are essentially just waiting for your network to come up, which seems a bit long. However, we know nothing about your network, nor why your particular network interfaces and network take so long to come up. It might be possible to reduce, but that will require much more research about your hardware and network...and another question.

Comment: `Startup finished in 20.418s (kernel) + 53.088s (userspace) = 1min 13.507s` — personally, I'm not too worried. I reboot once every few weeks. I never looked into why "it takes so long".  Just the BIOS takes like a minute to start the boot process. That's probably because I have 512Gb of RAM, but again, I'm not too worried.

Comment: Some more suggestions: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1187117/slow-boot-boot-19-10-tried-almost-everything & https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2417453 & 
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2417453&p=13857392#post13857392 & https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=linux-55-regression1&num=1