# slow boot after deleting partitions

Tags: boot, partitioning, kubuntu

Kubuntu 19.10

I deleted a different distro on the same disk as Kubuntu, it was before Kubuntu (i.e., to the left) and now I have a longer boot time.
The perceived delay is after I see the Kubuntu logo.
The system is i5 running on SSD with 8 Gb RAM.

Maybe something with fstab, and UUIDs that changed?
I will post some info that might help

```
$ systemd-analyze
Startup finished in 12.514s (firmware) + 5.159s (loader) + 34.727s (kernel) + 1min 30.361s (userspace) = 2min 22.763s 
graphical.target reached after 8.340s in userspace

systemd-analyze critical-chain
The time when unit became active or started is printed after the "@" characte
The time the unit took to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @8.340s
└─multi-user.target @8.339s
  └─kerneloops.service @8.316s +23ms
    └─network-online.target @8.302s
      └─NetworkManager-wait-online.service @1.894s +6.407s
        └─NetworkManager.service @1.736s +155ms
          └─dbus.service @1.728s
            └─basic.target @1.687s
              └─sockets.target @1.687s
                └─snapd.socket @1.681s +5ms
                  └─sysinit.target @1.678s
                    └─systemd-timesyncd.service @1.434s +242ms
                      └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service @1.398s +33ms
                        └─local-fs.target @1.391s
                          └─run-user-1000-gvfs.mount @8.766s
                            └─run-user-1000.mount @7.601s
                              └─local-fs-pre.target @263ms
                                └─keyboard-setup.service @189ms +73ms
                                  └─systemd-journald.socket @187ms
                                    └─system.slice @184ms
                                      └─-.slice @184ms

blkid
/dev/sda1: UUID="FD3A-C390" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI system partition" PARTUUID="33a74615-4c79-4b19-8c91-2d2805352162"
/dev/sda3: UUID="4C74491474490266" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Windows10" PARTUUID="20bf1505-887d-420f-bd62-29ec583418f2"
/dev/sda4: UUID="01D5E10606DD56C0" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="WindowsRecovery" PARTUUID="b0111e08-1738-402b-acd0-92f7945281bf"
/dev/sda5: UUID="9242ef31-5b4c-4868-9060-a20e36536a79" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="ec69ae6a-8c1a-4982-b3d3-bb825f88d015"
/dev/sda6: LABEL="VirtualMachine" UUID="01D5D9D0D313E8E0" TYPE="ntfs" PTTYPE="dos" PARTLABEL="VirtualMachine" PARTUUID="b4b302c8-ba8c-42c6-92d2-1dde7a39f2cf"
/dev/sda7: LABEL="rootMX19" UUID="c75d1c25-bb2d-4ee5-9fe2-1e9afb6f566d" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="bb39cdd3-efed-4fbc-bb83-9fb19adf62b1"
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="Personal Data" UUID="22EC446AEC4439F5" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="00000023-e770-4e21-09bc-d50146000000"
/dev/sdb2: LABEL="Backups" UUID="01D5DCC5C845E6F0" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="4f6ff0e0-bc09-01d5-70f8-a3a704deea00"
/dev/sdb3: LABEL="TimeShiftBackups" UUID="3764fe8e-b397-464c-b652-4a7c5de5de25" TYPE="ext4" PARTLABEL="TimeShiftBackups" PARTUUID="dc8ac5fe-f281-4b13-aea6-dbe2c490d220"

*fstab

# <file system> <mount point> <type> <options> <dump> <pass>

UUID=9242ef31-5b4c-4868-9060-a20e36536a79   /   ext4    errors=remount-ro   0   1
UUID=FD3A-C390  /boot/efi   vfat    umask=0077  0   1
/dev/disk/by-uuid/01D5B97BB5271110  /mnt/01D5B97BB5271110   auto    nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0   0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/22EC446AEC4439F5  /mnt/22EC446AEC4439F5   auto    nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0   0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/65924102-c27b-4bd3-a0b6-e8667989fb8d  /mnt/65924102-c27b-4bd3-a0b6-e8667989fb8d   auto    nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0   0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/01D5D9D0D313E8E0 /mnt/01D5D9D0D313E8E0 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/3764fe8e-b397-464c-b652-4a7c5de5de25 /mnt/3764fe8e-b397-464c-b652-4a7c5de5de25 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

Comment: 65924102-c27b-4bd3-a0b6-e8667989fb8d is in fstab but not in list of partitons? I prefer to  create mount points with name. And label any partitions I temporarily mount, so mounted by label not UUID. I do not know what is what with UUIDs.

Comment: Good catch. Maybe the system is looking for a non-existent partition If I delete the line with 65924102-c27b-4bd3-a0b6-e8667989fb8d from fstab, will that fix it?

Comment: It will help as it has to timeout looking for it. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1187117/slow-boot-boot-19-10-tried-almost-everything & 

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1018576/what-does-networkmanager-wait-online-service-do

Comment: I deleted the line but it still hangs at the Kubuntu logo. There must be a second place that I need to edit.

Comment: I replace quiet splash with this: noplymouth i915.fastboot=1 The noplymouth then does not show logo & shows boot process. With SSD now it often is so quick I cannot follow it, but I prefer to know what is going on. I may not need this now:  i915.fastboot=1 kernel parameter. Fastboot helps provide a clean, flicker-free Linux boot experience.
New 5.1 kernel will include it by default on Skylake and newer. I probably should remove that, as now I have 20.04 and 5.4 kernel.

Comment: This fixed it: sudo update-initramfs -u

Comment: Please make an answer with that so others can see how to fix this issue if it affects them.

Answer (score 2):

The solution requires two steps.

1. Remove from fstab the partition(s) that no longer exist. To do this, run `blkid` in the terminal. Then open `/etc/fstab` with root privileges and look for the UUID(s) that were not listed by `blkid`. Delete the line(s) that contain those UUID(s). Save and close.
2. Run this command in terminal:

   ```
   sudo update-initramfs -u
   ```

That should fix it. AFAIK this second step is required only in the Ubuntu-type distros.