# Slow boot after partitioning on Ubuntu 20.04 (not a swap issue)

Tags: boot, partitioning

I have repartitioned my SSD recently, and after that, my machine takes over 1 minute to boot. During the partitioning I deleted the swap partition and fixed the related problems with the help of  [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/639559/very-slow-boot-with-ubuntu-15-04).
It seems that my root partition takes 30 seconds to mount.
What am I missing?

`/etc/fstab`:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name 
devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda4 during installation
UUID=001df782-6f77-4838-a23b-ca9dae4c5265 /               ext4    
errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=AC24-A33D  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# /home was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=dea563d6-ef07-43c3-a181-c1aa2d074447 /home           ext4    
defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=a77231a3-8f96-4fa4-873e-628b5c1e6c18   none            swap    sw              0       0
```

`lsblk`:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 223.6G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0  14.7G  0 part [SWAP]
├─sda2   8:2    0   100M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda5   8:5    0  52.8G  0 part /
└─sda7   8:7    0 155.6G  0 part /home
sdb      8:16   0   1.8T  0 disk 
└─sdb1   8:17   0   1.8T  0 part
```

`dmesg`:

```
...
[    4.012563] Btrfs loaded, crc32c=crc32c-intel
[   35.535953] EXT4-fs (sda5): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[   35.678647] systemd[1]: Inserted module 'autofs4'
[   35.721534] systemd[1]: systemd 245.4-4ubuntu3.6 running in system mode. (+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ +LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD +IDN2 -IDN +PCRE2 default-hierarchy=hybrid)
[   35.738166] systemd[1]: Detected architecture x86-64.
[   35.759334] systemd[1]: Set hostname to <bilibraker-ThinkPad-T450>.
[   35.759850] Lockdown: systemd: /dev/mem,kmem,port is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
[   35.807724] systemd-sysv-generator[353]: stat() failed on /etc/init.d/httpd, ignoring: No such file or directory
[   35.813219] systemd-sysv-generator[353]: stat() failed on /etc/init.d/mysqld, ignoring: No such file or directory
[   35.909992] systemd[1]: Created slice system-modprobe.slice.
[   35.910245] systemd[1]: Created slice system-systemd\x2dfsck.slice.
[   35.910430] systemd[1]: Created slice User and Session Slice.
[   35.910480] systemd[1]: Started Forward Password Requests to Wall Directory Watch.
[   35.910688] systemd[1]: Set up automount Arbitrary Executable File Formats File System Automount Point.
[   35.910726] systemd[1]: Reached target User and Group Name Lookups.
[   35.910737] systemd[1]: Reached target Remote File Systems.
[   35.910745] systemd[1]: Reached target Slices.
[   35.910759] systemd[1]: Reached target System Time Set.
[   35.910766] systemd[1]: Reached target System Time Synchronized.
[   35.910869] systemd[1]: Listening on Syslog Socket.
[   35.910936] systemd[1]: Listening on fsck to fsckd communication Socket.
[   35.910975] systemd[1]: Listening on initctl Compatibility Named Pipe.
[   35.911123] systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Audit Socket.
[   35.911186] systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Socket (/dev/log).
[   35.911259] systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Socket.
[   35.911342] systemd[1]: Listening on udev Control Socket.
[   35.911398] systemd[1]: Listening on udev Kernel Socket.
[   35.912194] systemd[1]: Mounting Huge Pages File System...
[   35.913063] systemd[1]: Mounting POSIX Message Queue File System...
[   35.914352] systemd[1]: Mounting Kernel Debug File System...
[   35.915692] systemd[1]: Mounting Kernel Trace File System...
[   35.917176] systemd[1]: Starting Journal Service...
[   35.918810] systemd[1]: Starting Set the console keyboard layout...
[   35.920280] systemd[1]: Starting Create list of static device nodes for the current kernel...
[   35.920365] systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Load Kernel Module drm being skipped.
[   35.920945] systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Set Up Additional Binary Formats being skipped.
[   35.920986] systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in File System Check on Root Device being skipped.
[   35.923590] systemd[1]: Starting Load Kernel Modules...
[   35.924748] systemd[1]: Starting Remount Root and Kernel File Systems...
[   35.926112] systemd[1]: Starting udev Coldplug all Devices...
[   35.927413] systemd[1]: Starting Uncomplicated firewall...
[   35.929595] systemd[1]: Mounted Huge Pages File System.
[   35.929916] systemd[1]: Mounted POSIX Message Queue File System.
[   35.930176] systemd[1]: Mounted Kernel Debug File System.
[   35.930413] systemd[1]: Mounted Kernel Trace File System.
[   35.931046] systemd[1]: Finished Create list of static device nodes for the current kernel.
[   35.940197] EXT4-fs (sda5): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
[   35.941957] systemd[1]: Finished Remount Root and Kernel File Systems.
[   35.943491] systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Rebuild Hardware Database being skipped.
[   35.943529] systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Platform Persistent Storage Archival being skipped.
[   35.946542] systemd[1]: Starting Load/Save Random Seed...
[   35.947905] systemd[1]: Starting Create System Users...
[   35.967176] lp: driver loaded but no devices found
[   35.969578] bpfilter: Loaded bpfilter_umh pid 388
[   35.969894] Started bpfilter
[   35.982598] systemd[1]: Finished Load/Save Random Seed.
[   35.984767] systemd[1]: Finished Create System Users.
[   35.986045] systemd[1]: Starting Create Static Device Nodes in /dev...
[   35.986065] ppdev: user-space parallel port driver
[   35.996791] systemd[1]: Finished Load Kernel Modules.
[   35.998251] systemd[1]: Mounting FUSE Control File System...
[   35.999547] systemd[1]: Mounting Kernel Configuration File System...
[   36.000740] systemd[1]: Starting Apply Kernel Variables...
[   36.010567] systemd[1]: Mounted FUSE Control File System.
[   36.010964] systemd[1]: Mounted Kernel Configuration File System.
[   36.027814] systemd[1]: Finished Create Static Device Nodes in /dev.
[   36.029113] systemd[1]: Starting udev Kernel Device Manager...
[   36.031437] systemd[1]: Finished Set the console keyboard layout.
[   36.031657] systemd[1]: Reached target Local File Systems (Pre).
[   36.035785] systemd[1]: Finished Apply Kernel Variables.
[   36.038451] systemd[1]: Started Journal Service.
[   36.046875] systemd-journald[362]: Received client request to flush runtime journal.
[   36.620178] cfg80211: Loading compiled-in X.509 certificates for regulatory database
[   36.620487] cfg80211: Loaded X.509 cert 'sforshee: 00b28ddf47aef9cea7'
[   36.623305] RAPL PMU: API unit is 2^-32 Joules, 4 fixed counters, 655360 ms ovfl timer
[   36.623307] RAPL PMU: hw unit of domain pp0-core 2^-14 Joules
[   36.623308] RAPL PMU: hw unit of domain package 2^-14 Joules
[   36.623308] RAPL PMU: hw unit of domain dram 2^-14 Joules
[   36.623309] RAPL PMU: hw unit of domain pp1-gpu 2^-14 Joules
[   36.656911] Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
[   36.656913] Copyright(c) 2003- 2015 Intel Corporation
[   36.677432] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Found debug destination: EXTERNAL_DRAM
[   36.677435] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Found debug configuration: 0
[   36.677776] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: loaded firmware version 29.1654887522.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[   36.721482] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 7265, REV=0x210
[   36.735234] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[   36.736438] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Allocated 0x00400000 bytes for firmware monitor.
[   36.744453] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: base HW address: 94:65:9c:1e:a6:04
[   36.756759] Non-volatile memory driver v1.3
[   36.765038] thinkpad_acpi: ThinkPad ACPI Extras v0.26
[   36.765040] thinkpad_acpi: http://ibm-acpi.sf.net/
[   36.765041] thinkpad_acpi: ThinkPad BIOS JBET51WW (1.16 ), EC JBHT14WW
[   36.765042] thinkpad_acpi: Lenovo ThinkPad T450, model 20BUS0EW11
[   36.769565] thinkpad_acpi: radio switch found; radios are enabled
[   36.769588] thinkpad_acpi: This ThinkPad has standard ACPI backlight brightness control, supported by the ACPI video driver
[   36.769589] thinkpad_acpi: Disabling thinkpad-acpi brightness events by default...
[   36.784648] thinkpad_acpi: rfkill switch tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: radio is unblocked
[   36.808197] thinkpad_acpi: battery 2 registered (start 0, stop 100)
[   36.810364] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[   36.810374] thinkpad_acpi: battery 1 registered (start 0, stop 100)
[   36.810380] battery: new extension: ThinkPad Battery Extension
[   36.810447] input: ThinkPad Extra Buttons as /devices/platform/thinkpad_acpi/input/input12
[   36.810810] thermal thermal_zone3: failed to read out thermal zone (-61)
[   36.817849] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:03.0: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])
[   36.832484] input: HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/sound/card0/input13
[   36.832556] input: HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/sound/card0/input14
[   36.832627] input: HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/sound/card0/input15
[   36.832702] input: HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=9 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/sound/card0/input16
[   36.832763] input: HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=10 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/sound/card0/input17
[   36.843573] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0: autoconfig for ALC3232: line_outs=1 (0x14/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:speaker
[   36.843577] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0:    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[   36.843579] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0:    hp_outs=2 (0x16/0x15/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[   36.843580] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0:    mono: mono_out=0x0
[   36.843581] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0:    inputs:
[   36.843583] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0:      Dock Mic=0x19
[   36.843585] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0:      Mic=0x1a
[   36.843586] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0:      Internal Mic=0x12
[   36.904907] input: HDA Intel PCH Dock Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card1/input18
[   36.904986] input: HDA Intel PCH Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card1/input19
[   36.905063] input: HDA Intel PCH Dock Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card1/input20
[   36.905128] input: HDA Intel PCH Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card1/input21
[   36.940446] intel_rapl_common: Found RAPL domain package
[   36.940449] intel_rapl_common: Found RAPL domain core
[   36.940450] intel_rapl_common: Found RAPL domain uncore
[   36.940451] intel_rapl_common: Found RAPL domain dram
[   36.953691] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0
[   36.970273] Adding 15353852k swap on /dev/sda1.  Priority:-2 extents:1 across:15353852k SSFS
[   37.044959] EXT4-fs (sda7): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[   37.136263] audit: type=1400 audit(1632445166.795:2): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/cups/backend/cups-pdf" pid=740 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   37.136269] audit: type=1400 audit(1632445166.795:3): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=740 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   37.136272] audit: type=1400 audit(1632445166.795:4): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/cupsd//third_party" pid=740 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   37.139507] audit: type=1400 audit(1632445166.799:5): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/tcpdump" pid=741 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   37.147669] audit: type=1400 audit(1632445166.807:6): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="ippusbxd" pid=742 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   37.150533] audit: type=1400 audit(1632445166.811:7): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="nvidia_modprobe" pid=743 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   37.150537] audit: type=1400 audit(1632445166.811:8): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="nvidia_modprobe//kmod" pid=743 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   37.164055] audit: type=1400 audit(1632445166.823:9): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/bin/man" pid=748 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   37.164059] audit: type=1400 audit(1632445166.823:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="man_filter" pid=748 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   37.164061] audit: type=1400 audit(1632445166.823:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="man_groff" pid=748 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   38.223221] Lockdown: Xorg: raw io port access is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
[   38.605663] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[   38.703867] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[   38.705159] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
[   38.720836] vboxdrv: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[   38.731420] vboxdrv: Found 4 processor cores
[   38.750939] vboxdrv: TSC mode is Invariant, tentative frequency 2294684551 Hz
[   38.750940] vboxdrv: Successfully loaded version 6.1.22 (interface 0x00300000)
[   38.961270] VBoxNetFlt: Successfully started.
[   38.964017] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   38.964046] NET: Registered protocol family 31
[   38.964047] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   38.964051] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   38.964054] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   38.964058] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   38.964979] VBoxNetAdp: Successfully started.
[   39.010334] mc: Linux media interface: v0.10
[   39.027983] videodev: Linux video capture interface: v2.00
[   39.102543] usbcore: registered new interface driver btusb
[   39.118003] Bluetooth: hci0: read Intel version: 370810011003110e00
[   39.119066] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware file: intel/ibt-hw-37.8.10-fw-1.10.3.11.e.bseq
[   39.141794] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   39.141796] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   39.141803] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   39.187184] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device Integrated Camera (04f2:b449)
[   39.203546] input: Integrated Camera: Integrated C as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-8/2-8:1.0/input/input22
[   39.204143] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device HD Web Camera (05a3:9331)
[   39.247096] uvcvideo: Failed to query (GET_INFO) UVC control 12 on unit 2: -32 (exp. 1).
[   39.273105] uvcvideo: Failed to query (GET_INFO) UVC control 11 on unit 2: -32 (exp. 1).
[   39.299943] input: HD Web Camera: HD Web Camera as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-3/2-3.4/2-3.4:1.0/input/input23
[   39.300092] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
[   39.300093] USB Video Class driver (1.1.1)
[   39.407988] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0xfc2f
[   39.425024] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel firmware patch completed and activated
[   39.515665] NET: Registered protocol family 38
[   39.886153] usb 2-3.4: Warning! Unlikely big volume range (=3072), cval->res is probably wrong.
[   39.886156] usb 2-3.4: [6] FU [Mic Capture Volume] ch = 1, val = -1536/1536/1
[   39.886347] usbcore: registered new interface driver snd-usb-audio
[   40.612009] Lockdown: systemd-logind: hibernation is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
[   40.622856] Lockdown: systemd-logind: hibernation is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
[   40.829743] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   40.829750] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   40.829754] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[   42.477105] wlp3s0: authenticate with c4:3c:ea:eb:61:fc
[   42.481985] wlp3s0: send auth to c4:3c:ea:eb:61:fc (try 1/3)
[   42.483954] wlp3s0: authenticated
[   42.486125] wlp3s0: associate with c4:3c:ea:eb:61:fc (try 1/3)
[   42.487192] wlp3s0: RX AssocResp from c4:3c:ea:eb:61:fc (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=2)
[   42.489000] wlp3s0: associated
[   42.573474] wlp3s0: Limiting TX power to 30 (30 - 0) dBm as advertised by c4:3c:ea:eb:61:fc
[   42.574426] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp3s0: link becomes ready
[   50.174235] usb 3-2: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[   50.195309] usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0bc2, idProduct=61b5, bcdDevice= 7.10
[   50.195315] usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[   50.195318] usb 3-2: Product: M3 Portable
[   50.195321] usb 3-2: Manufacturer: Seagate
[   50.195324] usb 3-2: SerialNumber: NM16H1L1
[   50.780814] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[   50.786134] scsi host3: uas
[   50.786257] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
[   50.787473] scsi 3:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Seagate  M3 Portable      0710 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[   50.788235] sd 3:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[   54.320166] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] 3907029167 512-byte logical blocks: (2.00 TB/1.82 TiB)
[   54.320169] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] 4096-byte physical blocks
[   54.320327] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[   54.320329] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 53 00 00 08
[   54.320624] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[   54.320880] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Optimal transfer size 33553920 bytes not a multiple of physical block size (4096 bytes)
[   54.669126]  sdb: sdb1
[   54.670963] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
[  490.811778] show_signal: 18 callbacks suppressed
[  490.811785] traps: ibus-ui-gtk3[4271] trap int3 ip:7f2de1f03295 sp:7ffef63fd970 error:0 in libglib-2.0.so.0.6400.6[7f2de1ec7000+84000]
[  490.811981] traps: nm-applet[4318] trap int3 ip:7f1372350295 sp:7ffca08a7a30 error:0 in libglib-2.0.so.0.6400.6[7f1372314000+84000]
[  490.831054] traps: blueman-tray[4411] trap int3 ip:7f86369ce295 sp:7ffd3c8efc10 error:0 in libglib-2.0.so.0.6400.6[7f8636992000+84000]
[  498.318741] traps: nm-applet[39940] trap int3 ip:7f7e8724a295 sp:7fff7e6eb1d0 error:0 in libglib-2.0.so.0.6400.6[7f7e8720e000+84000]
```

`systemd-analyze`:

```
Startup finished in 35.657s (kernel) + 9.383s (userspace) = 45.041s 
graphical.target reached after 9.031s in userspace
```

`systemd-analyze blame`:

```
6.800s NetworkManager-wait-online.service                                                       
1.405s vboxdrv.service                                                                          
1.025s dev-sda5.device                                                                          
 727ms blueman-mechanism.service                                                                
 500ms accounts-daemon.service                                                                  
 486ms udisks2.service                                                                          
 450ms systemd-logind.service                                                                   
 426ms apport-autoreport.service                                                                
 328ms plymouth-read-write.service                                                              
 303ms avahi-daemon.service                                                                     
 291ms NetworkManager.service                                                                   
 284ms networkd-dispatcher.service                                                              
 269ms polkit.service                                                                           
 242ms apport.service                                                                           
 239ms upower.service                                                                           
 239ms systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service                                                           
 237ms tlp.service                                                                              
 233ms ufw.service                                                                              
 225ms ModemManager.service                                                                     
 221ms lightdm.service                                                                          
 194ms plymouth-quit-wait.service                                                               
 191ms grub-common.service                                                                      
 190ms alsa-restore.service                                                                     
 170ms systemd-resolved.service                                                                 
 168ms wpa_supplicant.service                                                                   
 143ms preload.service                                                                          
 142ms systemd-journal-flush.service                                                            
 140ms lm-sensors.service                                                                       
 133ms systemd-udev-trigger.service                                                             
 132ms systemd-udevd.service                                                                    
 128ms rsyslog.service                                                                          
 121ms systemd-journald.service                                                                 
 112ms keyboard-setup.service                                                                   
 109ms colord.service                                                                           
 105ms e2scrub_reap.service                                                                     
 104ms gpu-manager.service                                                                      
 102ms apparmor.service                                                                         
  97ms user@1000.service                                                                        
  96ms systemd-timesyncd.service                                                                
  92ms pppd-dns.service                                                                         
  88ms uwsgi.service                                                                            
  87ms ssh.service                                                                              
  73ms systemd-modules-load.service                                                             
  68ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-AC24\x2dA33D.service                                    
  46ms ubuntu-fan.service                                                                       
  46ms setvtrgb.service                                                                         
  45ms dev-disk-by\x2duuid-a77231a3\x2d8f96\x2d4fa4\x2d873e\x2d628b5c1e6c18.swap                
  44ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-dea563d6\x2def07\x2d43c3\x2da181\x2dc1aa2d074447.service
  42ms kerneloops.service                                                                       
  41ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service                                                       
  36ms systemd-sysusers.service                                                                 
  36ms systemd-random-seed.service                                                              
  35ms systemd-sysctl.service                                                                   
  33ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service                                                           
  32ms binfmt-support.service                                                                   
  31ms plymouth-start.service                                                                   
  24ms grub-initrd-fallback.service                                                             
  23ms home.mount                                                                               
  22ms systemd-user-sessions.service                                                            
  22ms bluetooth.service                                                                        
  20ms user-runtime-dir@1000.service                                                            
  20ms systemd-backlight@leds:tpacpi::kbd_backlight.service                                     
  17ms dev-hugepages.mount                                                                      
  17ms systemd-remount-fs.service                                                               
  16ms boot-efi.mount                                                                           
  16ms dev-mqueue.mount                                                                         
  15ms sys-kernel-debug.mount                                                                   
  15ms systemd-update-utmp.service                                                              
  14ms sys-kernel-tracing.mount                                                                 
  14ms vboxweb-service.service                                                                  
  13ms console-setup.service                                                                    
  12ms proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.mount                                                            
  12ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount                                                            
  12ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service                                                     
  11ms sys-kernel-config.mount                                                                  
  10ms kmod-static-nodes.service                                                                
   8ms openvpn.service                                                                          
   7ms systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service                                      
   7ms rtkit-daemon.service                                                                     
   5ms vboxballoonctrl-service.service                                                          
   2ms vboxautostart-service.service
```

So far I have tried these:

[slow boot after deleting partitions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1209792/slow-boot-after-deleting-partitions)

[Boot much slower after partition resize](https://askubuntu.com/questions/643352/boot-much-slower-after-partition-resize)

[Slow boot time after resizing partitions. Editing fstab did not work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/843693/slow-boot-time-after-resizing-partitions-editing-fstab-did-not-work)

Comment: I'm not seeing where your root partition takes 30 seconds to mount. Instead I'm seeing `Startup finished in 35.657s (kernel) + 9.383s (userspace) = 45.041s` which is a really good time. There are no tricks or tweaks to make the kernel load faster.

Comment: Is the output of `fstab` above your *current* version? If you deleted the swap partition from your SSD, then you may want to look at removing the final line in `/etc/fstab` which mounts a swap partition. Commenting it out with a `#` may be sufficient to test whether this has any impact on your boot time.

Comment: @matigo Oh, sorry, I wasn't clear. I deleted the swap partition, but then I created another one.

Comment: @user535733 before partitioning it booted up under 30 seconds :/

Comment: Some more things to review? Are you using btrfs? What is sdb? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284302/is-it-possible-to-make-ubuntu-20-04-boot-faster

Comment: @oldfred I am not familiar with btrfs. The /dev/sdb is my external HDD.

Comment: I am not sure why it then is loading a btrfs driver? Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Turns out my SSD was dying... Today was its last day. rip