# Slow boot time in ubuntu with ssd

Tags: boot, ssd

I had only 7sec boot time with windows 10 with ssd. When I replaced it with Ubuntu 19.10 it got sucked and now taking a minute to boot the system though i've ssd.

Comment: The output of `systemd-analyze blame` may help

Comment: Review these, others with slow boot issues: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1187117/slow-boot-boot-19-10-tried-almost-everything & 

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1018576/what-does-networkmanager-wait-online-service-do & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/800479/ubuntu-16-04-slow-boot-apt-daily-service
 & https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2436900&p=13932499#post13932499
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2417453 & 
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2417453&p=13857392#post13857392  & https://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/ubuntu-beaver-slow-boot.html

Comment: Windows 'Fast Boot' enables a Hibernation-like state where Windows does not actually shut down completely, just hibernates on your internal drive. Please compare Ubuntu to Windows shut down completely by holding down SHIFT when you click on Shut Down.