# How to troubleshoot slow booting problem in Ubuntu 19.10?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, swap

Before installing Ubuntu on my 64GB USB2.0 flash drive i did some research on partition schemes.
 
Most of the websites recommended 2GB-8GB for root(/) partition .

But,to play on the safe side i set it to 10GB.
and guess what happened 1 weak later.
I get notified that only 1GB of root space is left !!!
I freaked out and changed the size of the partition a few hours back AND.IT.RUINED.THE.PERFORMANCE !!!
I had this configuration when i installed Ubuntu.
**root = 10GB**
**swap = 2GB**
**home ~ 50GB**
AND now, what i did is -

**root = 32GB**
**swap = 2GB**
**home ~ 28GB**

I was expecting better performance But what followed totally pissed me off.
**Now the OS boots in about 1.5 minutes !**
Please let me know how i can make the boot process faster !

Edit: Just remembered that before i changed the partitions i was having a problem with the CD drive popping out.So,i opened it up ,removed the ribbon cable(or whatever that's called), taped it and left it inside.So,my CD drive does not pop out every 20seconds. Do you think it has any impact on the performance ?
Please let me know what to do in this case.
Were those websites i followed wrong ? Or i did some mistake on the first place ?

**[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gueAI.png) is the screenshot of df -h**

**[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUh3s.png) is the screenshot of df -systemd-analyze blame

**[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2kkn.png) is a screenshot of my home directory .All the files with mono on it and the UUID file seems suspicious. Do check them out.****


**[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0KZNU.png) is the screenshot of systemd-analyze critical-chain**

Do ask me if you need more details to solve this problem 
Thanks already !

Comment: Never seen 2GB+ for / that is for the installer. Full install should have 25 to 30GB for /  if you have your data in /home and/or data partition(s). And only you know how much data you may have. Some have TBs of media, others just a little. If partitions are not full, then boot & response time is not related to partition size. Post this: `df -h`. There are many questions and answers on slow boot. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1187117/slow-boot-boot-19-10-tried-almost-everything & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1018576/what-does-networkmanager-wait-online-service-do

Comment: It's not clear if you want partitioning advice or boot troubleshooting advice or something else. Please edit your question and title to ask a single answerable question.

Comment: @user535733 sorry for the confusion . My actual problem is slow booting. What i suspect is that it is because of bad partitions i made. Hence i mentioned that detail. Please answer this question considering both.

Comment: Please add `systemd-analyze critical-chain` to your various screenshots.

Comment: @user535733 Done. Actually executing this command gives three similar outputs . So, i put one in the screenshots. If all three are required , do let me know ill put all of them .

Comment: Read `man systemd-analyze`