# Ubuntu 19.10, long time to boot, dual boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot

Windows loads in 15-20 seconds.

This is a new install on SSD [(GParted)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZc8t.png), I hardly have anything on Ubuntu.

I have 16gb RAM.

```
sudo systemd-analyze
Startup finished in 34.036s (kernel) + 3min 591ms (userspace) = 3min 34.628s 
graphical.target reached after 1min 50.997s in userspace
```

Most of the time was saved by adjusting UUID of swap area. However total load time is still almost a minute. Hangs on blank purple screen after Grub.

```
sudo systemd-analyze
Startup finished in 34.139s (kernel) + 22.915s (userspace) = 57.054s 
graphical.target reached after 22.908s in userspace
```

```
sudo systemd-analyze blame
         21.029s plymouth-quit-wait.service
          6.422s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
          2.077s e2scrub_reap.service
          1.176s snap-core-8935.mount
          1.162s snap-wine\x2dplatform\x2d3\x2dstable-6.mount
          1.161s snap-core18-1705.mount
          1.123s snap-gnome\x2dlogs-81.mount
          1.118s snap-gnome\x2dlogs-93.mount
          1.050s snap-chromium-1105.mount
           933ms snapd.service
           873ms systemd-logind.service
           688ms snap-gnome\x2dcalculator-501.mount
           680ms snap-gnome\x2dcharacters-495.mount
           626ms dev-nvme0n1p2.device
           590ms dev-loop12.device
           576ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-1f04d49a\x2dddda\x2d431e\x2db6
           564ms snap-notepad\x2dplus\x2dplus-227.mount
           562ms snap-telegram\x2ddesktop-1498.mount
           538ms snap-core18-1223.mount
           535ms dev-loop14.device
           523ms dev-loop0.device
           499ms dev-loop15.device
           485ms dev-loop16.device
           466ms upower.service
           445ms dev-loop17.device
           418ms dev-loop18.device
           387ms snapd.seeded.service
           381ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d28\x2d1804-71.mount
           380ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d28\x2d1804-116.mount
           380ms snap-core-7917.mount
           366ms dev-loop5.device
           349ms snap-wine\x2dplatform\x2druntime-123.mount
           320ms systemd-journald.service
           310ms dev-loop1.device
           308ms systemd-resolved.service
           307ms snap-gnome\x2dcalculator-704.mount
           298ms systemd-localed.service
           286ms dev-loop10.device
           276ms snap-spotify-41.mount
           276ms dev-loop6.device
           272ms dev-loop3.device
           268ms dev-loop2.device
           267ms systemd-hostnamed.service
           255ms snap-vlc-1397.mount
           254ms networkd-dispatcher.service
           254ms systemd-timesyncd.service
           252ms systemd-journal-flush.service
           249ms udisks2.service
           243ms dev-loop11.device
           242ms dev-loop9.device
           241ms dev-loop4.device
           224ms dev-loop8.device
           221ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1502.mount
           221ms ModemManager.service
           182ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
           175ms gpu-manager.service
           165ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1353.mount
           164ms snap-gnome\x2dcharacters-317.mount
           143ms dev-loop7.device
           142ms accounts-daemon.service
           140ms user@1000.service
           135ms NetworkManager.service
           130ms snap-code-31.mount
           128ms bluetooth.service
           125ms apport.service
           124ms rsyslog.service
           122ms thermald.service
           122ms wpa_supplicant.service
           111ms avahi-daemon.service
           110ms grub-common.service
           106ms loadcpufreq.service
            94ms dev-loop13.device
            66ms grub-initrd-fallback.service
            64ms systemd-udevd.service
            59ms keyboard-setup.service
            51ms apparmor.service
            49ms dev-loop19.device
            47ms dev-loop20.device
            43ms dev-disk-by\x2duuid-0a8cf929\x2dca4f\x2d4bd7\x2d87cd\x2d3b609cd
            43ms switcheroo-control.service
            40ms nvidia-persistenced.service
            40ms geoclue.service
            34ms pppd-dns.service
            31ms packagekit.service
            29ms cpufrequtils.service
            27ms gdm.service
            25ms colord.service
            22ms systemd-modules-load.service
            21ms polkit.service
            17ms plymouth-start.service
            12ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
            12ms dev-loop21.device
            11ms kerneloops.service
            11ms plymouth-read-write.service
            10ms systemd-rfkill.service
            10ms systemd-sysctl.service
             8ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
             8ms user-runtime-dir@1000.service
             7ms systemd-sysusers.service
             7ms systemd-update-utmp.service
             7ms dev-hugepages.mount
             7ms systemd-remount-fs.service
             7ms home.mount
             7ms kmod-static-nodes.service
             6ms dev-mqueue.mount
             5ms openvpn.service
             5ms systemd-user-sessions.service
             5ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
             5ms ufw.service
             5ms systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service
             4ms console-setup.service
             4ms systemd-random-seed.service
             3ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
             3ms rtkit-daemon.service
             3ms setvtrgb.service
             2ms snapd.socket
             2ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
             1ms sys-kernel-config.mount
```

```
systemd-analyze critical-chain
The time when unit became active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit took to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @22.908s
└─multi-user.target @22.908s
  └─kerneloops.service @8.290s +11ms
    └─network-online.target @8.287s
      └─NetworkManager-wait-online.service @1.864s +6.422s
        └─NetworkManager.service @1.727s +135ms
          └─dbus.service @1.720s
            └─basic.target @1.708s
              └─sockets.target @1.708s
                └─snapd.socket @1.705s +2ms
                  └─sysinit.target @1.705s
                    └─systemd-timesyncd.service @1.450s +254ms
                      └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service @1.435s +12ms
                        └─local-fs.target @1.434s
                          └─run-user-1000-doc.mount @6.901s
                            └─run-user-1000.mount @2.780s
                              └─swap.target @887ms
                                └─dev-disk-by\x2duuid-0a8cf929\x2dca4f\x2d4bd7\x
                                  └─dev-disk-by\x2duuid-0a8cf929\x2dca4f\x2d4bd7
```

Comment: Make sure fstab mounts are correct. See these questions on same issue. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1187117/slow-boot-boot-19-10-tried-almost-everything & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1018576/what-does-networkmanager-wait-online-service-do & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/800479/ubuntu-16-04-slow-boot-apt-daily-service & https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2417453 & Changes I did: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2436900&p=13932499#post13932499

Comment: @oldfred thanks, now it's way faster! UUIDs didn't match, so I adjusted etc/fstab. Though empty purple screen after selecting Ubuntu in Grub is still taking a bit long.