# Slow boot, dual boot SSD 19.10

Tags: boot, ssd, radeon, amdgpu, gigabyte

Never had so much trouble getting a Linux distro up and running without a problem. Arch and Pop!_OS wouldn't even let me boot.

I got the old reliable Ubuntu to boot and install correctly next to Windows 10 on an SSD. It is taking 11 seconds to boot for me which is ridiculous.

CPU: Ryzen 5 1600
Motherboard: [Gigabyte AB350N](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-AB350N-Gaming-WIFI-rev-10/sp#sp)
GPU: Radeon 5600xt

Critical Chain:

```
graphical.target @1min 43.248s
└─multi-user.target @1min 43.248s
  └─kerneloops.service @8.048s +11ms
    └─network-online.target @8.044s
      └─NetworkManager-wait-online.service @1.673s +6.369s
        └─NetworkManager.service @1.386s +286ms
          └─dbus.service @1.380s
            └─basic.target @1.377s
              └─sockets.target @1.377s
                └─snapd.socket @1.375s +2ms
                  └─sysinit.target @1.373s
                    └─systemd-timesyncd.service @1.155s +217ms
                      └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service @1.138s +15ms
                        └─local-fs.target @1.137s
                          └─run-user-124.mount @12.603s
                            └─swap.target @313ms
                              └─swapfile.swap @238ms +74ms
                                └─systemd-remount-fs.service @230ms +7ms
                                  └─systemd-journald.socket @224ms
```

Blame:

```
1min 41.563s plymouth-quit-wait.service
         10.796s gdm.service
          6.369s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
    1min 41.563s plymouth-quit-wait.service
         10.796s gdm.service
          6.369s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
          2.107s e2scrub_reap.service
           844ms snapd.service
           804ms dev-sda5.device
           673ms systemd-logind.service
           452ms systemd-resolved.service
           417ms upower.service
           410ms networkd-dispatcher.service
           367ms udisks2.service
           340ms ModemManager.service
           321ms systemd-journald.service
           310ms snap-gnome\x2dcharacters-317.mount
           289ms snap-core18-1223.mount
           288ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d28\x2d1804-71.mount
```

Thanks for the help everyone. I built this computer for a WFH/Gaming setup, the WFH part is not working out so well.

Comment: When you select Shutdown while holding down the Shift key in Windows and select to boot from Windows again, how long does that boot take from the time you select Windows from GRUB?

Comment: Check xorg logs under `/var/log/Xorg.log.0` and check for errors, may you need proprietary driver amdgpu-pro-20.10 which added support for rx5600xt

Comment: See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1187117/slow-boot-boot-19-10-tried-almost-everything & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1018576/what-does-networkmanager-wait-online-service-do & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/800479/ubuntu-16-04-slow-boot-apt-daily-service
 & what I did: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2436900&p=13932499#post13932499