# MIGRATING WINDOWS FROM SSD TO HDD TO INSTALL LINUX ON SSD

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, 20.04

I have read a lot of tutorial but no website seems to be very definite with the problem I am facing. I recently installed Linux Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on my laptop with 100GB given to the ext4 partition on my HDD. I am very impressed with linux but not so with the 1min+30secs bootup time. I want to make the system faster, hence move it to SSD(which already has Windows as described).
My Questions are as follows:

1.Can I just move the part of linux to ssd which is responsible for booting up?
---1.1 Will it cause any errors with the windows partitioning ?
---1.2 Will future Windows update cause a problem with it?
2. In case the above is not possible, I would like to move the Windows to HDD and then possibly migrate/reinstall linux on it(I do not have a lot of data in linux currently).
---2.1 Which would be the better option? Migration or Reinstallation
3 If my windows is moved to HDD, will it cause any future problem about loading up programs as the addresses and drives have changed? Will the default saving location also change for every program automatically ?

The Configuration of my laptop is as follows:

Storage  - 1 TB HDD+256GB SSD
CPU - Intel Core i5 (9th Gen) Processor
RAM - 8 GB DDR4 RAM
Graphics Processor - NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050
Operating System - 64bit

The results of `systemd-analyze blame` and `systemd-analyze critical-chain` are: 
!https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRZiZ.jpg and 
!https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlJtf.jpg     respectively

I am really new to all of this as I have entered college, I would like some guidance.
This is my first question here, I am sorry if it wasn't framed properly.
Thank you

Comment: You might want to search this site for systemd-analyze blame , used to figure out what takes time in booting.  Your problem may not be slow disk at all.

Comment: @ubfan1 thank you, I have attached the corresponding images too.

Comment: Think if your Windows is not using all the space on SSD, then need about ~30GBs for root(/) and keep a /home partition on HDD.  Most OSs like to keep around 20% free space in their partitions to work well and for upgrades.  Best to do a reinstallation of linux for this.  Use windows tools for windows partitions.

Comment: I would use Windows to shrink its NTFS by 30GB and use gparted to create a 30GB / (root) partition. The either have /home on HDD or data partition(s). You can have both an ext4 data partition and a NTFS data partition for shared data. You also can improve boot time. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1187117/slow-boot-boot-19-10-tried-almost-everything & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1018576/what-does-networkmanager-wait-online-service-do & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/800479/ubuntu-16-04-slow-boot-apt-daily-service My NVMe drive is down to under 9 sec, but I remove snaps also.

Comment: @crip659 Okay I will continue to do so.

Comment: @oldfred thank you so much , it cleared doubts :)

Comment: @oldfred Ive made a new question in continuation to your advice, can you give it a look here at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1240126/dualboot-ubuntu-20-04-with-windows-10-on-ssd-and-data-on-hdd       thank you so much !