# Ubuntu 20.04 Very Slow Boot [drm:drm_atomic_helper_wait_for_dependencies [drm_kms_helper]] *ERROR* flip_done timed out

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, kernel, 20.04

I have recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my new Razer Blade Stealth and installed the Nvidia Driver 450, but now the boot time is weird. It takes more than two minutes for the system to boot and be responsive at all. When booting with `nomodeset` passed as Kernel Parameter, it boots fine in a few seconds, but then the Nvidia Driver wouldn't be loaded...

After letting it boot (without nomodeset), these errors appear multiple times after running `dmesg`

```
[  151.867350] [drm:drm_atomic_helper_wait_for_dependencies [drm_kms_helper]] *ERROR* [CRTC:83:pipe A] flip_done timed out
[  162.107787] [drm:drm_atomic_helper_wait_for_dependencies [drm_kms_helper]] *ERROR* [CRTC:136:pipe B] flip_done timed out
[  172.348571] [drm:drm_atomic_helper_wait_for_dependencies [drm_kms_helper]] *ERROR* [CONNECTOR:191:eDP-1] flip_done timed out
[  182.588656] [drm:drm_atomic_helper_wait_for_dependencies [drm_kms_helper]] *ERROR* [CONNECTOR:212:DP-3] flip_done timed out
[  192.828967] [drm:drm_atomic_helper_wait_for_dependencies [drm_kms_helper]] *ERROR* [PLANE:31:plane 1A] flip_done timed out
[  203.068850] [drm:drm_atomic_helper_wait_for_dependencies [drm_kms_helper]] *ERROR* [PLANE:84:plane 1B] flip_done timed out
[  213.308649] [drm:drm_atomic_helper_wait_for_flip_done [drm_kms_helper]] *ERROR* [CRTC:83:pipe A] flip_done timed out
[  223.548542] [drm:drm_atomic_helper_wait_for_flip_done [drm_kms_helper]] *ERROR* [CRTC:136:pipe B] flip_done timed out
```

I have tried multiple things from other posts in the last few days without success, such as `acpi_backlight=video/none/native/vendor`, `video=SVIDEO-1:d`. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I normally wouldn't recommend this... but because you've got a brand new model... you may need a newer kernel than what comes stock on 20.04. Go to https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.7.15/ and download the latest **successful build** of non-latency files. Install at your own risk.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I will certainly try that. I haven't installed a whole lot of things yet, so if it goes wrong, I'll just reinstall.

Comment: You can also check for a newer BIOS at the manufacturer's web site. Do `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` to find your current version. Do this first.

Comment: Thanks again for your reply! I've just checked and there are no newer BIOS versions available. So I'll try to update the Kernel tomorrow.

Comment: Just to clarify... you don't want to download the low-latency files... just the other 4. And just so you know... the errors you're getting are Nvidia errors.

Comment: Try this... edit /etc/default/grub and change this line to **GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="video=SVIDEO-1:d quiet splash"**, then sudo update-grub. Reboot.

Comment: Some other Slow boot questions. If you have installed nVidia driver, you should not use nomodeset. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1187117/slow-boot-boot-19-10-tried-almost-everything & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1018576/what-does-networkmanager-wait-online-service-do & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/800479/ubuntu-16-04-slow-boot-apt-daily-service

Comment: @oldfred Yes correct. I only do this in order to make my system boot faster, but indeed, it should not be used. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: @heynnema Unfortunately passing `video=SVIDEO-1:d quiet splash` as Kernel Parameters makes no difference. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Let me know how the kernel updates go.

Comment: @heynnema Unfortunately they didn't do much. I'm now on Kernel `Linux 5.7.15-050715-generic x86_64` but still having the same issue. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Assuming that you're running Nvidia 450.57, I'd contact Nvidia support. Tell them it's a brand new model laptop/netbook, with the latest software/BIOS, and a built-in Nvidia card, and that nomodeset allows it to boot quickly, and tell them the error messages. See if they have any input.

Comment: Okay, I'll give that a shot. Thanks for your help. If Nvidia comes up with something that fixes it I'll let it know.

Comment: @heynnema I didn't hear anything yet from Nvidia. But I've been fiddling around with this again in the last few days. I'm guessing these error are Intel GPU Driver errors, can this be the case?

Because when I'm using `i915.modeset=0` I don't get these errors, but without this modesetting I get them...

Comment: i915.modeset=0 disables the video driver for the Intel internal video card, and should have no effect on the Nvidia. Are you switched to the Intel, or the Nvidia?

Comment: Well when I'm using the Intel driver (`nvidia.modeset=0`), then the errors occur. When I'm using the Nvidia card (`i915.modeset=0`) everything goes well, but only the USB-C Hub HDMI port is not detected... Running only on the Nvidia card without the slow boot is perfectly fine by me, but I really need the HDMI port to work, which does work when booting from the Intel GPU...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For me the following made everything work as it should.

In `/etc/default/grub` edit `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` to the following
`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="intremap=off"`.
After that run a `sudo update-grub`. After a reboot, everything should work fine.

**Edit 2020-11-17**

As user228343 suggested, `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="intremap=off quiet splash button.lid_init_state=open"` works perfectly to also make suspending work.

Comment: Thank you for this. This really help me with kernel 6.2.9 UKI/Unified Kernel from Fedora, where the i915 is locked, I can't even boot... which is... sucks... But with this, My Thinkpad X220 can live longer, and kept being for work! Thanks! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The solution provided by @Sander T works to get the nvidia drivers functioning properly, but then once the laptop suspends, it went into the sleep loop.
This was solved using: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RazerBlade
So my final grub update has:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="intremap=off quiet splash button.lid_init_state=open"
```

Comment: Thanks! I have been running into this issue for a while now and haven't been able to find the solution until now. Thank you! I have also updated the original answer with your comment.