# [drm:drm_atomic_helper_wait_for_dependencies [drm_kms_helper]] *ERROR*

Tags: dependencies, vmware

after minimal instalation of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS server I'm having this errors.
Ubuntu is running in VMware.

```
[10497.876681] [drm:drm_atomic_helper_wait_for_dependencies [drm_kms_helper]] *ERROR* [CRTC:38:crtc-o] flip_done timed out
[10508.116708] [drm:drm_atomic_helper_wait_for_dependencies [drm_kms_helper]] *ERROR* (PLANE:34:plane-o] flip_done timed out
[12164.435831] [drm: drm_atomic_helper_wait_for_dependencies (drm_kms_helper]] *ERROR* [CRTC:38:crtc-0] flip_done timed out
[12174.675778] [drm:drm_atomic_helper_wait_for_dependencies [drm_kms_helper]] *ERROR* (PLANE:34:plane-o] flip_done timed out
[14208.851623] [drm: drm_atomic_helper_wait_for_dependencies (drm_kms_helper]] *ERROR* [CRTC:38:crtc-0] flip_done timed out
[14219.091526] [drm:drm_atomic_helper_wait_for_dependencies [drm_kms_helper]] *ERROR* (PLANE:34:plane-o] flip_done timed out
```

I have found possibility to edit in /etc/default/grub to the following GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="intremap=off".
But this didn't helped.

On system is only minimal instalation, no GUI ... also last update was applied.

Thank you for your advice.

Comment: Is this helpfiull? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1266668/ubuntu-20-04-very-slow-boot-drmdrm-atomic-helper-wait-for-dependencies-drm-km

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't help solve my problem.