# Ubuntu 20.04 - drm_atomic_helper_wait_for_flip_done

Tags: boot, kernel, hdmi, drm

I've decided to start using linux (because... why not?), so I went through all the installation process without any problem, the system ask for rebooting, so I let it does.

But when the machine restarted, my screen started turning on and off twice and this message appeared:

[Photo of the message (It's not a VM so I couldn't take screenshot/copy the message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TIr5H.jpg)

And it stays stuck like this forever.

The screen I'm using is plugged to my pc with HDMI (the only common port between both of them). When I use another screen with VGA, Linux boots up nicely.

I've read that maybe the recent kernel could be the cause of the issue, but I also tried installing Ubuntu 18.04, and the error still appears.

I've also tried modifying the kernel's default grub command (in `/etc/default/grub`) by adding `video=SVIDEO-1:d` to the "DEFAULT" line.

I don't know what to look at now.
Any help/suggestion would be really appreciated.

My machine is a dell OptiPlex 390 with an i3 and no additional graphic card.
And the result of `inxi -G` is:

```
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics
  driver: i915 v: kernel
  Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.11 driver: modesetting
  unloaded: fbdev,vesa resolution: 1680x1050~60Hz
  OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel HD Graphics 2000 (SNB GT1)
  v: 3.3 Mesa 21.0.3
```

Comment: An I3 has an integrated Intel GPU, which should be supported by Linux. If you didn't install any "special" drivers, it should work out of the box. To get the device running, try to add "nomodeset" into the grub command line, like `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet nomodeset`. This flag should not be used always, but might get your pc running, Please pass the output of `inxi -G`and paste it into your answer (use the **edit** link below your question)

Comment: So, by adding "nomodeset" (wich makes the drivers loaded when the OS has booted) it keeps turning on and off my hdmi display and doesn't boot (without the parameter, it was turning in and off 3 times and then display the drm error)

Comment: I'll bookmark your question - since I haven't any negative experience with Intel for the last 15 years with Linux. I really hope someone could clear this up

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'll keep investigate!

Comment: is something helpfull https://askubuntu.com/questions/1266668/ubuntu-20-04-very-slow-boot-drmdrm-atomic-helper-wait-for-dependencies-drm-km/1292436#1292436   here?

Comment: Yeah, already tried this but if I understand the parameter, the command initiate the lip close sensor variable as if it was open. But I have a pc (so no lid) and I think the problem come from the driver...