# In which disk should I install ubuntu dual boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation, software-installation, hard-drive

### I bought a pc **(CSL multimedia PC, AMD A10-9700, Radeon R7, 16 GB DDR4, 23 "TFT" Sprint T4567 Windows 10 Home ")**.

i would like to install ubuntu dual boot. i will like to use ubuntu for programming and my daily use.
but question is in which disk should I install ubuntu for better performance.
currently I have installed ubutun in the disk: **(Hard drive: 1000 GB SATA, Seagate® / Toshiba / WD®)** it works but very slow and when I try to execute some of my code everything hangs.
i am wondering if i shouldn't install ubuntu in same disk as windows in disk (SSD Boot: SSD 240 GB Kingston) if it does? what is the **(Hard drive: 1000 GB SATA, Seagate® / Toshiba / WD®)** for.

### here are the details of the PC:

**- CPU: AMD A10-9700 APU (Accelerated Processing Unit) 4 × 3500 MHz, with TurboCORE technology up to 3800 MHz, integrated graphics unit

- CPU cooler: Silent cooler for socket AM3 + / FM1 / FM2 / AM4
- Boot SSD: SSD 240 GB Kingston
- 1. Hard disk: 1000 GB SATA, Seagate® / Toshiba / WD®
- Memory: 16 GB DDR4 RAM, dual channel, max. 2400 MHz, Crucial
- Graphics: AMD Radeon R7 graphics, max. 2 GB HyperMemory, DirectX® 12, VGA, HDMI
- Mainboard: ASUS® PRIME A320M-K, Socket AM4, AMD A320 chipset, 1 × M.2, 4 × SATA III (6 GBit / s), RAID support, 4 × USB 3.1, 2 × USB 2.0, 2 × front USB, 1 × PCIe 3.0 X16, 2 × PCIe 2.0 X1, 2 × PS / 2, 7.1 HD Audio (ALC887 Audio Codec)**

Comment: Do you have good backups? If so, just use Windows to shrink NTFS partition on SSD and do a new install into the unallocated space. You can have /home or data partition(s) on HDD. I typically use 30GB for / (root), if all data in other partitions. But even from HDD, system should not be slow. Just a bit slower booting & loading apps. Once in RAM, drive does not matter. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1187117/slow-boot-boot-19-10-tried-almost-everything & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1018576/what-does-networkmanager-wait-online-service-do

Comment: @oldfred  his problem seems more of Ubuntu working slow than booting slow.  He mentions ubuntu hanging and slow when doing some code work.  Seems more like his hardware not working well with Ubuntu.

Comment: This seems like an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem): The OP should really be asking about how to troubleshoot their slow system instead of assuming it's due to dual-boot. It's rarely due to dual-boot.

Comment: @user535733 The OP is asking if his choice of drive is causing Ubuntu to be slow, not because he dual booted.  I doubt that installing on his SSD will help since not asking about slow boot, but Ubuntu working slow.  I don't know enough but his Ubuntu should be fast on his hardware no matter what drive it is on.

Comment: maybe I haven't been very clear if this is the case then I apologize.
my questions are as follows:
1) in which disk should I install ubuntu in the SSD or HDD?
it is currently installed in the HDD but a bit slow.
2) if the best solution is to install in the SSD! So what do I use the 1000 GB of HDD for?