# Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS slow boot

Tags: boot

I ran the commands `systemd-analyze blame` and `systemd-analyze critical-chain`. I found that dev-loops are data needed to load snap-installed programs quicker and plymouth stops when everything stops (so it doesn't slow boot). It also prompts me to type password before I login, something wasn't happening before.

Edit: I also deleted all snaps, still nothing. I noticed at startup it shows receive error ,pci error, bad tlc .Although I googled it and didn't find anything to solve this problem.

Here's the output of the commands :

- **systemd-analyze blame**

  ```
     20.726s plymouth-quit-wait.service
     5.084s bolt.service
     2.435s dev-nvme0n1p1.device
     1.454s snapd.service
     1.301s dev-loop21.device
     1.280s dev-loop20.device
     1.270s dev-loop16.device
     1.267s dev-loop22.device
     1.264s dev-loop17.device
     1.263s dev-loop19.device
     1.262s dev-loop18.device
     1.258s dev-loop24.device
     1.252s dev-loop15.device
     1.238s dev-loop23.device
     1.236s dev-loop25.device
      878ms dev-loop14.device
      781ms systemd-rfkill.service
      526ms dev-loop13.device
      420ms dev-loop12.device
      335ms systemd-journal-flush.service
      312ms dev-loop10.device
      311ms dev-loop11.device
      280ms dev-loop7.device
  ```
- **systemd-analyze critical-chain**

```
    graphical.target @21.754s
        └─multi-user.target @21.754s
          └─snapd.seeded.service @2.173s +279ms
            └─snapd.service @717ms +1.454s
              └─basic.target @693ms
                └─sockets.target @693ms
                  └─snapd.socket @691ms +2ms
                    └─sysinit.target @688ms
                      └─systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service @3.006s +15m
                        └─system-systemd\x2dbacklight.slice @3.005s
                          └─system.slice @115ms
                            └─-.slice @111ms
```

Here's my SystemdAnalyzePlot.svg:

[image: SystemdAnalyzePlot.svg]

Comment: I do not use snaps, some like them. So I remove all snaps and if an application I want I install the .deb via synaptic or terminal. See these on slow boot: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1187117/slow-boot-boot-19-10-tried-almost-everything & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1018576/what-does-networkmanager-wait-online-service-do & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/800479/ubuntu-16-04-slow-boot-apt-daily-service

Comment: I disabled all snaps still nothing.