# Why booting of Ubuntu 20.04 takes so long? It takes around 8 minutes to boot up

Tags: boot, 20.04, services

systemd-analyze blame | head

57.305s man-db.service
54.258s plymouth-quit-wait.service
49.709s snapd.service
26.772s dev-sda3.device
25.647s networkd-dispatcher.service
23.209s apt-daily-upgrade.service
20.751s udisks2.service
19.714s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
17.401s logrotate.service
17.267s dev-loop9.device

Comment: That seems real slow. What system do you have. An SSD speeds boot a lot, but you can change a variety of settings. Are you using snaps? Some suggestions in each of these: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1187117/slow-boot-boot-19-10-tried-almost-everything & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1018576/what-does-networkmanager-wait-online-service-do & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/800479/ubuntu-16-04-slow-boot-apt-daily-service
 & https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2436900&p=13932499#post13932499
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2417453 &

Comment: Start by looking at /dev/sda3. It shouldn't take 27 seconds to mount. Check that the UUID in /etc/fstab is correct. Looks like your system takes about 1 minute from end of POST to the login screen. Please edit your question to elaborate on the other seven minutes.

Comment: FYI my man-db.service is 815ms so that might be a good place to start.