# Long Boot Time Due to Boot Drive?

Tags: boot, 20.04, ssd

My system is taking a very long time to boot at the moment.  Running `$ systemd-analyze blame`, I can see that my boot drive (Samsung SSD 970 EVO 500GB, /dev/nvme0n1p1) is the culprit:

```
1min 31.290s dev-nvme0n1p2.device                   
1min 30.516s dev-loop1.device                       
1min 30.500s dev-loop2.device                       
1min 30.466s dev-loop3.device                       
1min 30.464s dev-loop4.device                       
1min 30.442s dev-loop5.device                       
1min 30.373s dev-loop7.device                       
1min 30.371s dev-loop6.device                       
1min 30.365s dev-loop8.device                       
1min 30.352s dev-loop9.device                       
1min 30.304s dev-loop10.device                      
1min 30.295s dev-loop11.device                      
1min 30.283s dev-loop0.device                       
1min 30.268s dev-loop12.device                      
1min 30.169s dev-loop13.device                      
1min 30.100s dev-loop14.device                      
1min 30.069s dev-loop15.device                      
1min 29.993s dev-loop16.device                      
1min 29.974s dev-loop17.device
```

That being said, I'm not sure what all of the different loopX.device entries are and wondered if they have anything to do with the boot speed reduction?

In any case, how would I go about fixing this?
I'm on Ubuntu 20.04.

Thanks for any advice you can give.

Comment: Are you using snaps (the loop devices)? I prefer .deb so uninstall all snaps. Have you updated UEFI & SSD firmware? My Samsung NVMe drive has an ISO for updating. It booted (looked like old DOS screen). https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284302/is-it-possible-to-make-ubuntu-20-04-boot-faster/1284332#1284332 & https://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/minisite/ssd/download/tools/ https://askubuntu.com/questions/1187117/slow-boot-boot-19-10-tried-almost-everything & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1018576/what-does-networkmanager-wait-online-service-do

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. Removing snap has left me with just: 1min 30.257s dev-nvme0n1p2.device, which I hope the updater can fix. I will test this out.

Comment: Mine is 432ms dev-nvme0n1p3.device. My last boot shows this: Startup finished in 3.301s (kernel) + 3.629s (userspace) = 6.931s 
graphical.target reached after 3.615s in userspace