# Ubuntu 20.04 takes too long to boot up

Tags: boot, 20.04, plymouth

I have been having an issue with linux boot up it takes like more than an hour I always end Up forcing my laptop to shutdown and keep opening it until it opens.

I ran the follwoing command

```
systemd-analyze blame
```

and the output was the follwoing

```
Bootup is not yet finished (org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager.FinishTimestampMonotonic=0).
Please try again later.
Hint: Use 'systemctl list-jobs' to see active jobs
```

When I ran the command listed in hint I found out that plymouth-quit-wait.service was running and other jobs were waiting on it so I stopped it and re-ran the analyze cmd and this was the output

```
23h 9min 7.830s plymouth-quit-wait.service      //<- This takes one day!!                      
   1min 21.185s plymouth-read-write.service                          
        32.321s grub-common.service                                  
        32.143s apport.service                                       
        32.028s lvm2-lvmpolld.service                                
        29.685s apt-daily.service                                    
        21.733s docker.service                                       
        17.724s logrotate.service                                    
        15.973s dev-sda6.device
```

How can I solve this issue

Comment: Some things to review: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284302/is-it-possible-to-make-ubuntu-20-04-boot-faster & https://askubuntu.com/questions/1187117/slow-boot-boot-19-10-tried-almost-everything & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1018576/what-does-networkmanager-wait-online-service-do & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/800479/ubuntu-16-04-slow-boot-apt-daily-service

Comment: "plymouth-quit-wait.service      //<- This takes one day!!".  "and other jobs were waiting on it "  Nope. It is not the one that makes you wait... it is the one that waits for you: it is waiting at the grub screen for an enter. It is something else that is the issue and this is a side-effect.

Comment: add results of `systemctl list-dependencies --reverse plymouth-quit-wait.service` :)

Comment: @Rinzwind `systemctl list-dependencies --reverse plymouth-quit-wait.service` output might be a shock as there is not much to output. ;)

Comment: @Rinzwind The output of the command you listed `plymouth-quit-wait.service
● └─multi-user.target
●   └─graphical.target`