Help me, my boot time is almost 2 minutes
My pc has 32gb ram, ryzen 7 5800x3d, and 4070 super running Ubuntu 24.04  . Yet for some reason my boot time is 2 minute :( I'm new to linux so if theres any other info/logs needed let me know plz
Here are the logs of systemd-analyze
Startup finished in 27.727s (firmware) + 5.689s (loader) + 1min 12.259s (kernel) 
+ 12.621s (userspace) = 1min 58.297s graphical.target reached after 12.613s in userspace.

and and systemd-analyze critical-chain
graphical.target @12.613s
└─multi-user.target @12.613s
  └─kerneloops.service @12.600s +12ms
    └─network-online.target @12.586s
      └─NetworkManager-wait-online.service @3.495s +9.091s
        └─NetworkManager.service @2.744s +735ms
          └─dbus.service @2.467s +197ms
            └─basic.target @2.458s
              └─sockets.target @2.458s
                └─snapd.socket @2.445s +12ms
                  └─sysinit.target @2.413s
                    └─systemd-resolved.service @2.268s +145ms
                      └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service @2.189s +60ms
                        └─local-fs.target @2.168s
                          └─run-snapd-ns-snapd\x2ddesktop\x2dintegration.mnt.mo>
                            └─run-snapd-ns.mount @4.057s
                              └─local-fs-pre.target @429ms
                                └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service @421ms +7ms
                                  └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev-early.service @4>
                                    └─kmod-static-nodes.service @390ms +8ms
                                      └─systemd-journald.socket @386ms
                                        └─-.mount @363ms
                                          └─-.slice @363ms


lastly
systemd-analyze blame

9.091s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
4.641s plymouth-quit-wait.service
 779ms snapd.seeded.service
 753ms boot-efi.mount
 735ms NetworkManager.service
 562ms fwupd.service
 526ms e2scrub_reap.service
 474ms snapd.service
 468ms apport.service
 306ms udisks2.service
 299ms dev-sdc2.device
 280ms avahi-daemon.service
 279ms bluetooth.service
 279ms gnome-remote-desktop.service
 264ms polkit.service
 262ms power-profiles-daemon.service
 253ms accounts-daemon.service
 248ms switcheroo-control.service
 197ms dbus.service
 179ms user@1000.service
 177ms dev-loop4.device
 175ms dev-loop5.device
 172ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
 171ms dev-loop1.device
 154ms dev-loop0.device
 152ms dev-loop3.device
 149ms gpu-manager.service
 147ms dev-loop7.device
 146ms dev-loop6.device
 145ms systemd-resolved.service
 139ms ModemManager.service
 127ms rsyslog.service
 115ms dev-loop2.device
 107ms upower.service
  96ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-D76C\x2d365C.service
  86ms grub-common.service
  84ms apparmor.service
  81ms apport-autoreport.service
  75ms update-notifier-download.service
  69ms secureboot-db.service
  68ms systemd-logind.service
  66ms systemd-journald.service
  66ms gdm.service
  62ms dev-loop8.device
  60ms systemd-udevd.service
  60ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
  58ms sysstat.service
  54ms systemd-modules-load.service
  51ms snapd.apparmor.service
  49ms thermald.service
  48ms systemd-oomd.service
  45ms systemd-timesyncd.service
  40ms systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service
  39ms plymouth-start.service
  39ms colord.service
  36ms cups.service
  35ms keyboard-setup.service
  35ms systemd-journal-flush.service
  30ms systemd-random-seed.service
  26ms grub-initrd-fallback.service
  25ms wpa_supplicant.service
  21ms snap-bare-5.mount
  20ms snap-core22-1380.mount
  20ms systemd-remount-fs.service
  20ms snap-firefox-4173.mount
  19ms snap-firmware\x2dupdater-127.mount
  18ms snap-gnome\x2d42\x2d2204-176.mount
  17ms systemd-binfmt.service
  17ms nvidia-persistenced.service
  16ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1535.mount
  15ms snap-snap\x2dstore-1124.mount
  14ms plymouth-read-write.service
  14ms snap-snapd-21465.mount
  13ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev-early.service
  13ms alsa-restore.service
  13ms snap-snapd\x2ddesktop\x2dintegration-157.mount
  12ms snapd.socket
  12ms kerneloops.service
  10ms dev-hugepages.mount
  10ms dev-mqueue.mount
  10ms systemd-sysctl.service
  10ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
   9ms sys-kernel-tracing.mount
   9ms proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.mount
   9ms var-snap-firefox-common-host\x2dhunspell.mount
   8ms kmod-static-nodes.service
   8ms modprobe@configfs.service
   8ms systemd-update-utmp.service
   8ms rtkit-daemon.service
   7ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
   7ms modprobe@drm.service
   6ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
   6ms modprobe@fuse.service
   6ms swap.img.swap
   5ms systemd-user-sessions.service
   5ms user-runtime-dir@1000.service
   5ms sysstat-collect.service
   4ms console-setup.service
   4ms systemd-rfkill.service
   4ms ufw.service
   4ms modprobe@loop.service
   4ms modprobe@efi_pstore.service
   4ms openvpn.service
   4ms sys-kernel-config.mount
   3ms modprobe@dm_mod.service
   3ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
   1ms e2scrub_all.service
   1ms setvtrgb.service


I had recently messed up deleting a dual boot so thats probably why the firmware time is so long, which I dont mind too much. Not sure what logs to show for that issue. But after reinstalling my dual boot (windows +linux) Ubuntu loads soooo slow compared to windows. Any and all help would be appreciated.
Edit: cat /etc/fstab
 /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sdc2 during curtin installation
/dev/disk/by-uuid/66d80e88-9a11-4921-a2dd-cfadb969a09f / ext4 defaults 0 1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sdc1 during curtin installation
/dev/disk/by-uuid/D76C-365C /boot/efi vfat defaults 0 1
/swap.img   none    swap    sw  0   0



Try running sudo update-grub and reboot. Also post the output of cat /etc/fstab (Ubuntu might be stuck trying to find the old windows installation drive at boot, and fstab might indicate that)

added to post @ArchismanPanigrahi

Are you using SSD? Have you updated UEFI firmware and if SSD its firmware? Some changes you may want to consider:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1187117/slow-boot-boot-19-10-tried-almost-everything & https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284302/is-it-possible-to-make-ubuntu-20-04-boot-faster &
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1018576/what-does-networkmanager-wait-online-service-do &
https://askubuntu.com/questions/800479/ubuntu-16-04-slow-boot-apt-daily-service Advanced changes:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Improving_performance/Boot_process

Is swap.img a swapfile that you created, or something else? Temporarily comment that out in fstab, reboot, and see if it boots faster.
