# Awfully slow boot and shutdown times on all AMD system. Once fully booted, all is somewhat fine

Tags: boot, drivers, 20.04, shutdown

System Specs:

- Ubuntu 20.04 on kernel 5.7.1 using Wayland
- AMD Ryzen 9 3950x
- Gigabyte X570 Aorus Pro Wi-Fi
- Sapphire Nitro+ 5700XT
- 1TB Inland Premium M.2 NVMe
- 2x32GB G.Skill Ripjaws 3600 CL18

Upon a fresh install, Ubuntu was playing very poorly with my GPU hooked up to two monitors. Updated kernel and that was solved. The consistent issue, however, has been slow and glitchy boot times. Shutdown times are equally frustrating on top of giving some errors, halting for 30s to 2m before shutting down. I’ve also had zero success in maintaining any bluetooth connection for any useful amount of time.

I ran a systemd—analyze blame command and found a network-wait service that took 15s. Shut that down. Now Plymouth-quit-wait.service shows up taking 25s along with colord.service at 6s. I’m at a loss as to even begin searching for the culprit. Hardware issues? Windows ran fine. Bad install? Faulty driver support? Blah

[Here’s the message prompt upon shutdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKWOr.jpg)

I rebooted the machine while typing this. On top of the previous symptoms, the favorites bar took a solid 15 minutes to populate. Programs have always loaded up just fine otherwise.

Comment: Plymouth doesn't cause any slowdown in boot/shutdown, read https://askubuntu.com/questions/1119167/slow-boot-issue-due-to-plymouth-quit-wait-service-ubuntu-18-04. colord isn't strictly necessary for a system, so try disabling that as well. (sudo systemctl disable colord).

Comment: Paste the output of `systemd-analyze time` and `systemd-analyze blame`

Comment: Inspect your bootlog:  `journalctl -b > bootlog.txt`