# How do I speed up Ubuntu 20.04 boot time

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 20.04, systemd

Booting up into Ubuntu 20.04 takes a long time for me. I ran the `systemd-analyze` command and this is what I get.

```
Startup finished in 5.533s (kernel) + 1min 40.647s (userspace) = 1min 46.181s 
graphical.target reached after 1min 40.553s in userspace
```

How do I reduce the userspace time and can someone explain what it is.

The following is the output of `systemd-analyze blame`

```
systemd-analyze blame
1min 12.349s plymouth-quit-wait.service                           
     15.221s snapd.service                                        
     13.732s networkd-dispatcher.service                          
     13.096s dev-sda4.device                                      
     10.283s NetworkManager-wait-online.service                   
      8.650s udisks2.service                                      
      8.511s gpu-manager.service                                  
      7.907s NetworkManager.service                               
      7.089s dev-loop0.device                                     
      7.089s dev-loop1.device                                     
      7.015s dev-loop3.device                                     
      6.753s dev-loop6.device                                     
      6.645s dev-loop9.device                                     
      6.614s accounts-daemon.service                              
      6.603s dev-loop18.device                                    
      6.552s dev-loop8.device                                     
      6.467s dev-loop12.device                                    
      6.361s dev-loop13.device                                    
      6.257s dev-loop14.device                                    
      6.193s dev-loop15.device                                    
      6.149s dev-loop17.device                                    
      6.139s dev-loop16.device                                    
      5.774s polkit.service                                       
lines 1-23...skipping...
1min 12.349s plymouth-quit-wait.service                           
     15.221s snapd.service                                        
     13.732s networkd-dispatcher.service                          
     13.096s dev-sda4.device                                      
     10.283s NetworkManager-wait-online.service                   
      8.650s udisks2.service                                      
      8.511s gpu-manager.service                                  
      7.907s NetworkManager.service                               
      7.089s dev-loop0.device                                     
      7.089s dev-loop1.device                                     
      7.015s dev-loop3.device                                     
      6.753s dev-loop6.device                                     
      6.645s dev-loop9.device                                     
      6.614s accounts-daemon.service                              
      6.603s dev-loop18.device                                    
      6.552s dev-loop8.device                                     
      6.467s dev-loop12.device                                    
      6.361s dev-loop13.device                                    
      6.257s dev-loop14.device                                    
      6.193s dev-loop15.device                                    
      6.149s dev-loop17.device                                    
      6.139s dev-loop16.device                                    
      5.774s polkit.service                                       
      4.736s avahi-daemon.service                                 
      4.735s bluetooth.service                                    
      4.312s switcheroo-control.service                           
      4.281s dev-loop11.device                                    
      4.259s systemd-journal-flush.service                        
      4.246s dev-loop4.device                                     
      4.191s dev-loop10.device                                    
      4.070s bolt.service                                         
      4.062s dev-loop5.device                                     
      4.041s fwupd.service                                        
      3.943s dev-loop7.device                                     
      3.503s thermald.service                                     
      3.500s wpa_supplicant.service                               
      3.500s systemd-logind.service                               
      3.300s systemd-resolved.service                             
      3.217s grub-common.service                                  
      3.142s apport.service                                       
      3.072s e2scrub_reap.service                                 
      2.712s systemd-udevd.service                                
      2.582s grub-initrd-fallback.service                         
      2.193s secureboot-db.service                                
      2.165s ModemManager.service                                 
      1.813s rsyslog.service                                      
      1.798s gdm.service                                          
      1.556s systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service                       
      1.432s apparmor.service                                     
      1.424s pppd-dns.service                                     
      1.232s systemd-modules-load.service                         
      1.156s snapd.apparmor.service                               
      1.082s snap-vlc-1700.mount                                  
      1.056s snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d34\x2d1804-36.mount
```

I am using a Dell G7 17

i7 9750H

Nvidia RTX 2070 MaxQ

16GB 2666 RAM

256GB SSD + 1TB HDD

Thanks

Edit #1

I have reinstalled Ubuntu 20.04 but my time has not changed even though I did a minimal installation. I did install VLC, Terminator and Jupyter Notebooks to carry out my tasks.

Here are the new times.

```
nova@G7:~$ systemd-analyze blame 
37.821s plymouth-quit-wait.service                           
13.609s dev-sda4.device                                      
13.119s networkd-dispatcher.service                          
11.606s NetworkManager-wait-online.service                   
10.705s systemd-journal-flush.service                        
 9.914s udisks2.service                                      
 8.143s accounts-daemon.service                              
 8.063s dev-loop1.device                                     
 8.008s dev-loop2.device                                     
 7.920s fwupd.service                                        
 7.846s dev-loop4.device                                     
 7.665s dev-loop10.device                                    
 7.654s dev-loop11.device                                    
 7.082s dev-loop8.device                                     
 6.791s dev-loop5.device                                     
 6.660s NetworkManager.service                               
 6.494s dev-loop9.device                                     
 5.541s polkit.service                                       
 5.309s dev-loop7.device                                     
 5.224s dev-loop12.device                                    
 5.154s dev-loop13.device                                    
 4.965s gpu-manager.service                                  
 4.951s bluetooth.service                                    
 4.949s avahi-daemon.service                                 
 4.766s dev-loop0.device                                     
 4.418s switcheroo-control.service                           
 4.414s thermald.service                                     
 4.413s wpa_supplicant.service                               
 4.412s systemd-logind.service                               
 4.344s dev-loop6.device                                     
 4.251s ModemManager.service                                 
 4.035s apport.service                                       
 3.922s grub-common.service                                  
 3.853s dev-loop3.device                                     
 3.341s bolt.service                                         
 3.033s secureboot-db.service                                
 2.699s rsyslog.service                                      
 2.370s systemd-resolved.service                             
 2.183s systemd-udevd.service                                
 1.818s gdm.service                                          
 1.783s grub-initrd-fallback.service                         
 1.695s systemd-modules-load.service                         
 1.309s keyboard-setup.service                               
 1.219s plymouth-start.service                               
 1.138s systemd-random-seed.service                          
 1.135s apparmor.service                                     
 1.093s snapd.seeded.service                                 
 1.000s snapd.apparmor.service                               
  945ms colord.service                                       
  872ms systemd-sysusers.service                             
  852ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service                   
  801ms systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service  
  760ms modprobe@drm.service                                 
  708ms e2scrub_reap.service                                 
  678ms systemd-rfkill.service                               
  671ms snap-telegram\x2ddesktop-2064.mount                  
  658ms snap-vlc-1700.mount                                  
  585ms snapd.service                                        
  572ms snap-canonical\x2dlivepatch-95.mount                 
  524ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service                       
  514ms upower.service                                       
  504ms systemd-udev-trigger.service                         
  493ms swapfile.swap                                        
  484ms snap-spotify-42.mount                                
  467ms snap-jupyter-6.mount                                 
  443ms systemd-journald.service                             
  438ms snap-core20-634.mount                                
  422ms pppd-dns.service                                     
  407ms kerneloops.service                                   
  406ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-E2FE\x2dB8EE.service
  371ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d34\x2d1804-24.mount               
  353ms openvpn.service                                      
  345ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d28\x2d1804-128.mount              
  339ms snap-snap\x2dstore-433.mount                         
  321ms setvtrgb.service                                     
  307ms ufw.service                                          
  291ms user@1000.service                                    
  280ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1506.mount              
  279ms systemd-remount-fs.service                           
  266ms snap-snapd-7264.mount                                
  261ms systemd-sysctl.service                               
  242ms systemd-timesyncd.service                            
  227ms snap-core-9993.mount                                 
  194ms console-setup.service                                
  177ms systemd-update-utmp.service                          
  154ms plymouth-read-write.service                          
  146ms snap-discord-115.mount                               
  132ms snap-core18-1705.mount                               
  128ms snap-snapd-9279.mount                                
  103ms dev-hugepages.mount                                  
  102ms dev-mqueue.mount                                     
  102ms sys-kernel-debug.mount                               
  101ms sys-kernel-tracing.mount                             
   99ms systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service                       
   99ms kmod-static-nodes.service                            
   88ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d34\x2d1804-36.mount               
   77ms snap-snap\x2dstore-467.mount                         
   60ms rtkit-daemon.service                                 
   48ms boot-efi.mount                                       
   46ms systemd-user-sessions.service                        
   33ms snap-core18-1885.mount                               
   20ms dev-loop16.device                                    
   14ms dev-loop15.device                                    
    9ms user-runtime-dir@1000.service                        
    7ms dev-loop14.device                                    
    7ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service                 
    6ms alsa-restore.service                                 
    3ms dev-loop17.device                                    
    1ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount                        
    1ms sys-kernel-config.mount                              
  478us snapd.socket
```

Edit #2

After the install I have noticed apps like the Ubuntu Software and other inbuilt apps also take time to load.

Ubuntu is loaded on a partition of my HDD

Comment: Could you add some info about the hardware you're using? Also, perhaps check out this question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1119167/slow-boot-issue-due-to-plymouth-quit-wait-service-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: Updated the post as per your request. Also, I checked the post you linked it does reduce the overall boot time but increases the time taken by each service and applications also take time load. Will edit after disabling Snapd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things that helped me speed up my PC.

#### 1. Reinstalling Ubuntu.

While reinstalling make sure you choose the minimal installation option as this will reduce the number of applications and packages installed on your PC. You can always manually add whatever is needed using the terminal.

#### 2. Use an SSD.

On my PC Ubuntu is installed on my Hard drive which makes the bootup time slower

#### 3. When Dual Booting a PC use the First Partition of the drive.

When I first Dual Booted Ubuntu on my HDD the first partition was for storing the data used by Windows. After this, there were some necessary portions created by Windows and at last the partition for Ubuntu.
The computer scans all the partitions in order and then boots into Ubuntu when it reaches the Ubuntu drive (sdb4 in my case).

Doing all this now my boot time has reduced significantly.