# How long should it take to boot up Ubuntu?

Tags: boot, 20.04, boot-time

I am currently using 'Ubuntu 20.04 LTS' (No dual boot) on 'hp da0077tx' laptop (Configuration: i5 8th gen CPU, 8 GB RAM, 1 TB HDD and 2 GB Nvidia GeForce MX110 graphics). I've purchased this laptop in Oct, 2018.

This is the output of `systemd-analyze`:

```
Startup finished in 5.240s (firmware) + 4.251s (loader) + 3.468s (kernel) + 2min 8.150s (userspace) = 2min 21.110s 
graphical.target reached after 2min 8.034s in userspace
```

Output of `systemd-analyze blame`:

```
1min 46.814s plymouth-quit-wait.service                                               
 34.552s apt-daily.service                                                        
 10.905s snapd.service                                                            
  9.814s dev-sda4.device                                                          
  8.481s NetworkManager-wait-online.service                                       
  8.316s udisks2.service                                                          
  7.591s networkd-dispatcher.service                                              
  6.261s fwupd-refresh.service                                                    
  6.258s accounts-daemon.service                                                  
  5.687s NetworkManager.service                                                   
  5.619s dev-loop5.device                                                         
  5.526s dev-loop10.device                                                        
  5.102s bolt.service                                                             
  4.829s polkit.service                                                           
  4.642s dev-loop9.device                                                         
  4.519s dev-loop6.device                                                         
  4.507s dev-loop8.device                                                         
  4.448s systemd-journal-flush.service                                            
  3.830s avahi-daemon.service                                                     
  3.829s bluetooth.service                                                        
  3.828s dev-loop7.device                                                         
  3.764s switcheroo-control.service                                               
  3.758s thermald.service                                                         
  3.756s systemd-logind.service                                                   
  3.754s wpa_supplicant.service                                                   
  3.651s dev-loop2.device                                                         
  3.643s dev-loop3.device                                                         
  3.589s dev-loop0.device                                                         
  3.509s dev-loop1.device                                                         
  2.792s gpu-manager.service                                                      
  2.636s grub-initrd-fallback.service                                             
  2.587s upower.service                                                           
  2.473s ModemManager.service                                                     
  2.460s grub-common.service                                                      
  1.770s apport.service                                                           
  1.738s motd-news.service                                                        
  1.526s user@125.service                                                         
  1.448s systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service                                           
  1.393s systemd-udevd.service                                                    
  1.355s systemd-sysctl.service                                                   
  1.141s rsyslog.service                                                          
  1.055s snap-core18-1880.mount                                                   
  1.049s e2scrub_reap.service                                                     
   995ms systemd-resolved.service                                                 
   972ms snap-core18-1885.mount                                                   
   972ms apparmor.service                                                         
   930ms systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service                      
   927ms systemd-modules-load.service                                             
   859ms gdm.service                                                              
   799ms keyboard-setup.service                                                   
   751ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d34\x2d1804-33.mount                                   
   740ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d34\x2d1804-36.mount                                   
   706ms snap-google\x2dcloud\x2dsdk-145.mount                                    
   705ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1506.mount                                  
   660ms systemd-random-seed.service                                              
   583ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
   504ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service                                       
   497ms nvidia-persistenced.service                                              
   478ms plymouth-start.service                                                   
   454ms colord.service                                                           
   433ms pppd-dns.service                                                         
   420ms snap-snap\x2dstore-415.mount                                             
   419ms snapd.apparmor.service                                                   
   401ms modprobe@drm.service                                                     
   374ms user@1000.service                                                        
   368ms snap-snap\x2dstore-467.mount                                             
   346ms systemd-sysusers.service                                                 
   301ms systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service                                           
   296ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-0D16\x2d291D.service                    
   295ms systemd-journald.service                                                 
   215ms systemd-remount-fs.service                                               
   213ms systemd-timesyncd.service                                                
   199ms systemd-user-sessions.service                                            
   188ms user-runtime-dir@125.service                                             
   152ms kerneloops.service                                                       
   149ms apport-autoreport.service                                                
   139ms kmod-static-nodes.service                                                
   137ms snap-snapd-8542.mount                                                    
   125ms snapd.seeded.service                                                     
   113ms setvtrgb.service                                                         
   104ms dev-disk-by\x2duuid-9b6b620a\x2d2051\x2d471a\x2d8c49\x2d94590d110a68.swap
    97ms snap-snapd-8790.mount                                                    
    92ms dev-hugepages.mount                                                      
    92ms dev-mqueue.mount                                                         
    92ms ufw.service                                                              
    91ms sys-kernel-debug.mount                                                   
    91ms sys-kernel-tracing.mount                                                 
    65ms console-setup.service                                                    
    49ms snap-google\x2dcloud\x2dsdk-146.mount                                    
    48ms boot-efi.mount                                                           
    44ms rtkit-daemon.service                                                     
    42ms openvpn.service                                                          
    39ms plymouth-read-write.service                                              
    32ms systemd-update-utmp.service                                              
    27ms systemd-rfkill.service                                                   
    21ms user-runtime-dir@1000.service                                            
    10ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service                                     
     9ms alsa-restore.service                                                     
     2ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount                                            
     2ms dev-loop11.device                                                        
     2ms sys-kernel-config.mount                                                  
   780us snapd.socket
```

Output of `systemd-analyze critical-chain`:

```
The time when unit became active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit took to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @2min 8.034s
└─multi-user.target @2min 8.034s
  └─kerneloops.service @29.505s +152ms
    └─network-online.target @29.487s
      └─NetworkManager-wait-online.service @21.005s +8.481s
        └─NetworkManager.service @15.314s +5.687s
          └─dbus.service @15.311s
            └─basic.target @15.284s
              └─sockets.target @15.284s
                └─snapd.socket @15.282s +780us
                  └─sysinit.target @15.088s
                    └─systemd-timesyncd.service @14.874s +213ms
                      └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service @13.424s +1.448s
                        └─local-fs.target @13.420s
                          └─run-user-125-gvfs.mount @30.185s
                            └─run-user-125.mount @25.688s
                              └─swap.target @13.299s
                                └─dev-disk-by\x2duuid-9b6b620a\x2d2051\x2d471a\x2d8c49\x2d94590d110a68.swap @13.194s +104ms
                                  └─dev-sda3.device @13.193s
```

Sometimes, I feel my laptop is taking longer to boot up than expected. So, is this the time it should take to boot up or it is actually taking longer? If it is taking longer, then what should I do to reduce the boot time?

I know there are some similar questions but they either use SSD or have better CPU or more amount of RAM. But I currently don't want to purchase new hardware, So, Is there any way to reduce the boot time without changing hardware.

Sorry if this is a Duplicate question.

Comment: You should add the results of `systemd-analyze blame`. That shows a list of units and their time needed. And `systemd-analyze critical-chain` should show moments where units have to wait for another unit

Comment: more than 2 minutes is definitely not normal for a decently recent laptop. Look at the boot logs. Check whether / is still owned by root!

Comment: This is probably the answer https://askubuntu.com/a/1121100/15811 to your problem

Comment: @Melebius, Thanks for your response. There's no kernel update available for Ubuntu 20.04. My kernel version: `5.4.0-42-generic`.