# Long startup time in ubuntu 20.04.with SSD

Tags: 20.04, ssd, startup, single-user

I switched from windows 10 to Ubuntu 20.04.1 desktop single boot. Having SSD in my system the startup time in windows was in order of seconds. But in Ubuntu I am getting a start up time of 1 min  42 seconds.

This is what I got after running: systemd-analyze blame:

[image: This is what I got after running: systemd-analyze blame]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to decrease the boot time](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1166486/how-to-decrease-the-boot-time)

Comment: Please copy and paste the output from the terminal instead of the screenshot. this makes it easier to to read.

Comment: Some additional changes you can try: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284302/is-it-possible-to-make-ubuntu-20-04-boot-faster

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to diagnose/fix very slow boot on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030867/how-to-diagnose-fix-very-slow-boot-on-ubuntu-18-04)

Comment: With regards to your plymouth-quit-wait.service, [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1119167/slow-boot-issue-due-to-plymouth-quit-wait-service-ubuntu-18-04) may shed some light.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the `NetworkManager-wait-online` if you don't have a bunch of resources on the network that need to be connected *before* signing in. If you do not run your notebook on a corporate LAN, chances are you can go without it.

Do these things after Ubuntu eventually finishes booting:

1. Open a terminal
2. Disable the Network Manager wait:
   `sudo systemctl disable NetworkManager-wait-online.service`
3. Reboot

Problem solved. If you *do* need to restore this function later, you can do so like this:

```
sudo systemctl enable NetworkManager-wait-online.service
```

Hope this helps