# Why does Ubuntu boot so slowly? Conflicting messages

Tags: boot, snap, systemd, 20.10, plymouth

I have been going through these forums trying to figure out exactly what is going on.
First:

```
pc@my_pc: uname -a
Linux my_pc 5.8.0-45-generic #51-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 19 13:24:51 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

My pc is a Lenovo Legion Y545 and I am running Ubuntu 20.10 dual-booted with Windows.

I went through a sluggish boot this morning. This is what I get:

```
pc@my_pc: systemd-analyze time
Startup finished in 6.568s (firmware) + 4.890s (loader) + 5.536s (kernel) + 2min 31.339s (userspace) = 2min 48.334s 
graphical.target reached after 2min 31.330s in userspace
```

```
pc@my_pc: systemd-analyze blame 
1min 55.831s plymouth-quit-wait.service                           
     26.497s apt-daily-upgrade.service                            
     24.608s man-db.service                                       
     17.170s systemd-journal-flush.service                        
     15.791s networkd-dispatcher.service                          
     14.018s dev-sda4.device                                      
     13.332s udisks2.service                                      
     12.832s snapd.service                                        
     11.636s logrotate.service                                    
     11.411s accounts-daemon.service                              
      7.947s avahi-daemon.service                                 
      7.943s bluetooth.service                                    
      7.934s NetworkManager.service                               
      7.893s apache2.service                                      
      7.872s polkit.service                                       
      7.300s dev-loop5.device                                     
      6.689s dev-loop6.device                                     
      6.627s dev-loop9.device                                     
      6.238s dev-loop12.device                                    
      5.895s dev-loop11.device                                    
      5.859s dev-loop7.device                                     
      5.775s dev-loop4.device                                     
      5.755s dev-loop8.device                                     
      5.615s fwupd.service                                        
      5.603s dev-loop0.device                                     
      5.556s dev-loop10.device                                    
      5.420s gdm.service                                          
      5.413s switcheroo-control.service                           
      5.162s ModemManager.service                                 
      5.034s apport.service                                       
      4.841s systemd-resolved.service                             
      4.750s grub-common.service                                  
      4.540s systemd-logind.service                               
      4.539s thermald.service                                     
      4.537s wpa_supplicant.service                               
      4.509s apparmor.service                                     
      4.157s dev-loop1.device                                     
      4.078s dev-loop2.device                                     
      3.920s secureboot-db.service                                
      3.919s rsyslog.service                                      
      3.661s e2scrub_reap.service                                 
      3.660s gpu-manager.service                                  
      3.563s nvidia-persistenced.service                          
      3.562s pppd-dns.service                                     
      3.173s upower.service                                       
      2.359s systemd-udevd.service                                
      2.084s colord.service                                       
      2.073s systemd-rfkill.service                               
      1.486s kerneloops.service                                   
      1.255s systemd-random-seed.service                          
      1.169s openvpn.service                                      
      1.161s systemd-sysusers.service
```

```
pc@my_pc: systemd-analyze critical chain
graphical.target @2min 31.330s
└─multi-user.target @2min 31.330s
  └─snapd.service @2min 18.496s +12.832s
    └─snap-snapd-11402.mount @1min 54.289s +29ms
      └─dev-loop13.device @1min 54.316s +2ms
```

My first thought was *"Plymouth-quit-wait.service is to blame here*". According to this link [Slow boot issue due to plymouth-quit-wait.service + ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1119167/slow-boot-issue-due-to-plymouth-quit-wait-service-ubuntu-18-04) however, it is not the case. My second thought was that, by looking at the critical chain output, I can see what is going on. I see that dev-loop13.device seems to be taking a lot of time. However, in the blame output, dev-loop13.device is only taking up 2ms of time. The same kind of discrepancy can be said about snapd service.

Finally I used plymouth-quit-wait.service as a parameter for critical-chain. Below is what I got

```
pc@my_pc: systemd-analyze critical-chain plymouth-quit-wait.service
The time when unit became active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit took to start is printed after the "+" character.

plymouth-quit-wait.service +1min 55.831s
└─systemd-user-sessions.service @32.380s +212ms
  └─network.target @31.581s
    └─NetworkManager.service @23.646s +7.934s
      └─dbus.service @23.638s
        └─basic.target @23.589s
          └─sockets.target @23.588s
            └─snapd.socket @23.584s +2ms
              └─sysinit.target @23.439s
                └─systemd-timesyncd.service @23.243s +195ms
                  └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service @22.130s +1.066s
                    └─systemd-journal-flush.service @4.959s +17.170s
                      └─systemd-journald.service @4.224s +734ms
                        └─systemd-journald.socket @4.209s
                          └─system.slice @3.295s
                            └─-.slice @3.295s
```

Needless to say I am a bit lost. Other posts here have more specific issues where the problem is more or less clear from error messages. I am not sure how to interpret my messages. What exactly appears to be the issue and how can I fix it? Any suggestions?

Comment: Here's what I see right away: You have both NetworkManager (a desktop feature) running on the same systems as Apache2 (a server feature). So this isn't a stock install -- you've been twiddling with it and bolting extra parts on. Try removing a few that you are no longer using...or at least disable them so they don't start at boot.

Comment: `26.497s apt-daily-upgrade.service` means that the system has been shut down for a while -- long enough for the next apt-daily-upgrade timer to have passed. This should not happen every boot, since that timer is set to a random time each day.

Comment: `12.832s snapd.service` suggests that you had a snap which needed to update. That also suggests that your system has been shut down a while. Snapd checks for updates four times each day. This should not happen every boot

Comment: Thank you for your quick replies @user535733

Comment: I fixed up the apache2 thing by disabling it, then rebooting. The start up time seemed to be much faster. Now I am at a boot time of 1 min 23.146 seconds with graphical target reached at 1 min 6.238 sec. It looks like the next big thing is

systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service @22.893s +1.028s

and other systemd stuff slowing down my boot

Comment: Try disable `NetworkManager-wait-online.service`. That has helped me, see here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1166486/how-to-decrease-the-boot-time?rq=1

Comment: Some more settings to review. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284302/is-it-possible-to-make-ubuntu-20-04-boot-faster