# Slow boot on Ubuntu 20.04 (details added)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 20.04, plymouth

I've got Ubuntu 20.04 on a dual boot machine and it takes a lot of time to boot. It didn't take that much when I first installed it, so I started to wonder why this happens.

This is what **systemd-analyze blame** return:

```
44.535s plymouth-quit-wait.service                                     
21.380s snapd.service                                                  
19.608s dev-sda6.device                                                
16.905s systemd-journal-flush.service                                  
15.430s apt-daily.service                                              
15.290s networkd-dispatcher.service                                    
11.667s udisks2.service                                                
11.560s dev-loop27.device                                              
11.101s dev-loop20.device                                              
11.050s NetworkManager-wait-online.service                             
11.009s dev-loop28.device                                              
10.990s dev-loop26.device                                              
10.860s dev-loop25.device                                              
10.799s dev-loop11.device                                              
10.733s dev-loop22.device                                              
10.556s dev-loop17.device                                              
10.439s dev-loop8.device                                               
10.323s dev-loop19.device                                              
10.192s dev-loop16.device                                              
10.096s dev-loop24.device                                              
 9.903s accounts-daemon.service                                        
 9.802s dev-loop21.device                                              
 9.677s dev-loop29.device                                              
 9.600s dev-loop18.device                                              
 9.505s dev-loop9.device                                               
 9.449s dev-loop4.device                                               
 9.009s dev-loop14.device                                              
 9.003s dev-loop23.device                                              
 8.603s NetworkManager.service                                         
 8.552s dev-loop13.device                                              
 8.077s dev-loop3.device                                               
 8.034s dev-loop15.device                                              
 7.032s dev-loop1.device                                               
 6.972s dev-loop7.device                                               
 6.850s dev-loop10.device                                              
 6.779s polkit.service                                                 
 6.488s dev-loop2.device                                               
 6.407s dev-loop0.device                                               
 6.221s dev-loop12.device                                              
 6.169s apport-autoreport.service                                      
 5.991s apache2.service                                                
 5.877s avahi-daemon.service                                           
 5.875s bluetooth.service                                              
 5.838s dev-loop5.device                                               
 5.806s ModemManager.service                                           
 5.500s switcheroo-control.service                                     
 5.492s thermald.service                                               
 5.489s wpa_supplicant.service                                         
 5.488s systemd-logind.service                                         
 4.938s dev-loop6.device                                               
 3.819s grub-common.service                                            
 3.630s loadcpufreq.service                                            
 3.550s systemd-rfkill.service                                         
 3.039s apport.service                                                 
 2.976s user@125.service                                               
 2.482s gdm.service                                                    
 2.292s rsyslog.service                                                
 2.141s gpu-manager.service                                            
 2.102s e2scrub_reap.service                                           
 2.029s snap-code-58.mount                                             
 1.966s plymouth-start.service                                         
 1.960s snap-code-59.mount                                             
 1.862s snap-core-10859.mount                                          
 1.861s snap-core-10908.mount                                          
 1.810s systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-D4FE\x2dF70C.service          
 1.737s secureboot-db.service                                          
 1.712s snap-core18-1944.mount                                         
 1.678s systemd-resolved.service                                       
 1.605s snap-core18-1988.mount                                         
 1.603s snapd.apparmor.service                                         
 1.508s snap-core20-875.mount                                          
 1.471s snap-core20-904.mount                                          
 1.460s upower.service                                                 
 1.448s snap-exercism-5.mount                                          
 1.380s systemd-udevd.service                                          
 1.342s snap-figma\x2dlinux-92.mount                                   
 1.340s snap-figma\x2dlinux-93.mount                                   
 1.303s snap-foliate-1137.mount                                        
 1.301s snap-foliate-1163.mount                                        
 1.235s snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d28\x2d1804-128.mount                        
 1.109s apparmor.service                                               
 1.083s snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d28\x2d1804-145.mount                        
  981ms systemd-modules-load.service                                   
  800ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d34\x2d1804-60.mount                         
  750ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d34\x2d1804-66.mount                         
  713ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service                                 
  707ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1513.mount                        
  676ms lm-sensors.service                                             
  603ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service                             
  599ms systemd-sysusers.service                                       
  586ms virtualbox.service                                             
  585ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1514.mount                        
  571ms systemd-random-seed.service                                    
  568ms keyboard-setup.service                                         
  567ms systemd-journald.service                                       
  550ms snap-kde\x2dframeworks\x2d5\x2dqt\x2d5\x2d14\x2dcore18-4.mount 
  537ms systemd-user-sessions.service                                  
  521ms snap-kde\x2dframeworks\x2d5\x2dqt\x2d5\x2d15\x2dcore20-14.mount
  483ms systemd-sysctl.service                                         
  474ms systemd-timesyncd.service                                      
  431ms grub-initrd-fallback.service                                   
  416ms snap-kolourpaint-56.mount                                      
  415ms snap-kolourpaint-59.mount                                      
  413ms snap-pick\x2dcolour\x2dpicker-238.mount                        
  396ms atopacct.service                                               
  394ms snapd.seeded.service                                           
  390ms vboxweb.service                                                
  376ms snap-spotify-45.mount                                          
  371ms systemd-udev-trigger.service                                   
  343ms snap-snapd-11107.mount                                         
  322ms pppd-dns.service                                               
  320ms cpufrequtils.service                                           
  292ms dev-hugepages.mount                                            
  291ms dev-mqueue.mount                                               
  289ms sys-kernel-debug.mount                                         
  288ms sys-kernel-tracing.mount                                       
  285ms systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service            
  283ms kmod-static-nodes.service                                      
  281ms modprobe@drm.service                                           
  278ms swapfile.swap                                                  
  262ms snap-vlc-1700.mount                                            
  260ms snap-spotify-46.mount                                          
  259ms snap-vlc-2103.mount                                            
  259ms colord.service                                                 
  254ms systemd-update-utmp.service                                    
  228ms user@1000.service                                              
  172ms systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service                                 
  158ms snap-snapd-11402.mount                                         
  154ms kerneloops.service                                             
  151ms systemd-remount-fs.service                                     
  129ms boot-efi.mount                                                 
  102ms openvpn.service                                                
   99ms phpsessionclean.service                                        
   95ms ufw.service                                                    
   90ms plymouth-read-write.service                                    
   87ms setvtrgb.service                                               
   82ms console-setup.service                                          
   82ms user-runtime-dir@125.service                                   
   26ms hddtemp.service                                                
   23ms user-runtime-dir@1000.service                                  
   18ms rtkit-daemon.service                                           
   10ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service                           
   10ms alsa-restore.service                                           
    6ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount                                  
    5ms sys-kernel-config.mount                                        
    1ms snapd.socket
```

Also I've read this answer ([Slow boot issue due to plymouth-quit-wait.service + ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1119167/slow-boot-issue-due-to-plymouth-quit-wait-service-ubuntu-18-04?newreg=14c1302247564a8dbf7b62e2922a92c5)
) and checked what plymouth-quit-wait.service is waiting for:

```
plymouth-quit-wait.service
● ├─system.slice
● └─sysinit.target
●   ├─apparmor.service
●   ├─dev-hugepages.mount
●   ├─dev-mqueue.mount
●   ├─keyboard-setup.service
●   ├─kmod-static-nodes.service
●   ├─plymouth-read-write.service
●   ├─plymouth-start.service
●   ├─proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.automount
●   ├─setvtrgb.service
●   ├─sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
●   ├─sys-kernel-config.mount
●   ├─sys-kernel-debug.mount
●   ├─sys-kernel-tracing.mount
●   ├─systemd-ask-password-console.path
●   ├─systemd-binfmt.service
●   ├─systemd-boot-system-token.service
●   ├─systemd-hwdb-update.service
●   ├─systemd-journal-flush.service
●   ├─systemd-journald.service
●   ├─systemd-machine-id-commit.service
●   ├─systemd-modules-load.service
●   ├─systemd-pstore.service
●   ├─systemd-random-seed.service
●   ├─systemd-sysctl.service
●   ├─systemd-sysusers.service
●   ├─systemd-timesyncd.service
●   ├─systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
●   ├─systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
●   ├─systemd-udev-trigger.service
●   ├─systemd-udevd.service
●   ├─systemd-update-utmp.service
●   ├─cryptsetup.target
●   ├─local-fs.target
●   │ ├─-.mount
●   │ ├─boot-efi.mount
●   │ ├─systemd-fsck-root.service
●   │ └─systemd-remount-fs.service
●   └─swap.target
●     └─swapfile.swap
```

Can you please let me know if there is something I can do? I'm new to Ubuntu so I don't really know what things can be safely uninstalled.

Thanks

Comment: [Removing snaps](https://www.kevin-custer.com/blog/disabling-snaps-in-ubuntu-20-04/) assuming you aren't using them looks like your biggest time savings. A better representation of boot time can be shown if you use the output from `systemd-analyze critical-chain`. BTW `plymouth` isn't really using any boot time. It is just running until boot completes.

Comment: It looks like you have installed a lot of software with snaps. You can install the .deb version and remove the snap. Some advantages & disadvantages of snap vs. .deb. Some things to review on slow boot. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284302/is-it-possible-to-make-ubuntu-20-04-boot-faster Links also may have more details.

Comment: Thanks to both, it helped a lot! I uninstalled every snap apps and disabled NetworkManager-wait-online.service