# How do I make my system boot faster?

Tags: boot

I don’t know how to make my system boot faster, can't really find useful information online as I followed almost all advice and just getting a few seconds faster.

I've got the hibernation enabled and for that I use a swap memory space of about 9GB (my RAM is 8GB, and supposedly is recommended at least as big as the RAM memory) I thought that maybe the boot parameters, as it needs to check some UUID spaces for booting from hibernation, were causing some delay.  But deleting those parameters in the boot didn't made any improvement. I also found curious that boot from hibernation doesn't take a lot of time whatsoever (7 to 10 seconds more or less)

Finally I got dual boot with Windows, but I got my GRUB set to a delay of 2 seconds and I think it's well optimised.

Here is the  `systemd-analyze critical-chain` output:

```
The time the unit took to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @1min 2.717s
└─multi-user.target @1min 2.717s
  └─plymouth-quit-wait.service @22.707s +40.009s
    └─systemd-user-sessions.service @22.596s +104ms
      └─network.target @22.591s
        └─NetworkManager.service @17.322s +5.266s
          └─dbus.service @17.320s
            └─basic.target @17.266s
              └─sockets.target @17.266s
                └─uuidd.socket @17.266s
                  └─sysinit.target @17.200s
                    └─systemd-update-utmp.service @16.854s +345ms
                      └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service @15.492s +1.324s
                        └─local-fs.target @15.451s
                          └─boot-efi.mount @15.373s +76ms
                            └─systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-FCAE\x2d6336.service @14.164s +1.180s
                              └─dev-disk-by\x2duuid-FCAE\x2d6336.device @14.163s
```

Here is the  `systemd-analyze blame` output:

```
40.009s plymouth-quit-wait.service
10.600s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
10.275s networkd-dispatcher.service
 8.334s udisks2.service
 7.877s accounts-daemon.service
 7.818s cups.service
 6.549s apache2.service
 5.266s NetworkManager.service
 4.612s dev-sda5.device
 4.469s gdm.service
 4.173s upower.service
 3.990s fwupd.service
 3.909s gpu-manager.service
 3.639s avahi-daemon.service
 3.638s bluetooth.service
 3.602s polkit.service
 3.138s switcheroo-control.service
 3.125s thermald.service
 3.119s systemd-logind.service
 2.858s apport.service
 2.804s wpa_supplicant.service
 2.345s grub-common.service
 1.812s packagekit.service
 1.715s rsyslog.service
 1.710s secureboot-db.service
 1.689s ModemManager.service
 1.511s e2scrub_reap.service
 1.500s plymouth-start.service
 1.329s update-notifier-download.service
 1.324s systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
 1.316s apparmor.service
 1.307s systemd-resolved.service
 1.200s nvidia-persistenced.service
 1.180s systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-FCAE\x2d6336.service
 1.028s systemd-modules-load.service
  815ms systemd-sysusers.service
  766ms systemd-random-seed.service
  758ms keyboard-setup.service
  682ms tlp.service
  623ms systemd-journald.service
  611ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
  588ms modprobe@drm.service
  572ms swapfile.swap
  523ms kerneloops.service
  485ms systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service
  449ms binfmt-support.service
  414ms systemd-udevd.service
  345ms systemd-update-utmp.service
  305ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
  297ms plymouth-read-write.service
  296ms colord.service
  287ms systemd-oomd.service
  271ms user@1000.service
  266ms grub-initrd-fallback.service
  259ms systemd-sysctl.service
  256ms systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service
  153ms systemd-timesyncd.service
  151ms setvtrgb.service
  137ms systemd-remount-fs.service
  123ms modprobe@mtdpstore.service
  115ms systemd-journal-flush.service
  108ms console-setup.service
  104ms systemd-user-sessions.service
   96ms modprobe@chromeos_pstore.service
   93ms ufw.service
   76ms boot-efi.mount
   63ms modprobe@configfs.service
   62ms modprobe@fuse.service
   48ms openvpn.service
   43ms proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.mount
   37ms geoclue.service
   32ms dev-hugepages.mount
   31ms dev-mqueue.mount
   30ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
   29ms sys-kernel-tracing.mount
   26ms kmod-static-nodes.service
   23ms rtkit-daemon.service
   13ms alsa-restore.service
   10ms modprobe@efi_pstore.service
    8ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
    6ms sys-kernel-config.mount
    5ms modprobe@pstore_blk.service
    5ms user-runtime-dir@1000.service
    4ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
    2ms modprobe@pstore_zone.service
    1ms modprobe@ramoops.service
```

And [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYKy7.jpg) the plot

I'll appreciate any help I could get. I don't know what could I do to make it boot faster, or if it's simply fast enough and I can't get any faster.

Comment: Let's see...you are starting Apache, CUPS, NetworkManager, gpu-manager, Avahi, Bluetooth, thermald, and other arguably non-essential services. These make your experience great, but they take time at boot.

Comment: Hibernation & large swaps are not now recommended. You may be able to boot just as fast as recovery from hibernation and avoid many issues. Have you reviewed these settings?https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284302/is-it-possible-to-make-ubuntu-20-04-boot-faster noplymount boot parameter
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1119167/slow-boot-issue-due-to-plymouth-quit-wait-service-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: How large should it be?

Comment: Are they gonna start after boot if I disable their start at boot?