# Ubuntu 22.04 booting very slowly

Tags: boot

I have an HP Z420 workstation, and I need to wait about 2 minutes while I get the login screen.

There are nothing special in boot.log

```
------------ Mon May 01 14:09:40 CEST 2023 ------------
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Listening on [0;1;39mLoad/Save RF Kill Switch Status /dev/rfkill Watch[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mShow Plymouth Boot Screen[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mForward Password Requests to Plymouth Directory Watch[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target [0;1;39mLocal Encrypted Volumes[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Found device [0;1;39mWDC_WD5000AAKX-75U6AA0 EFI\x20system\x20partition[0m.
         Starting [0;1;39mFile System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/BC5C-95FE[0m...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mFile System Check Daemon to report status[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Finished [0;1;39mFlush Journal to Persistent Storage[0m.
         Starting [0;1;39mLoad Kernel Module chromeos_pstore[0m...
         Starting [0;1;39mLoad Kernel Module efi_pstore[0m...
         Starting [0;1;39mLoad Kernel Module pstore_blk[0m...
         Starting [0;1;39mLoad Kernel Module pstore_zone[0m...
         Starting [0;1;39mLoad Kernel Module ramoops[0m...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Finished [0;1;39mFile System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/BC5C-95FE[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Finished [0;1;39mLoad Kernel Module efi_pstore[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Finished [0;1;39mLoad Kernel Module pstore_blk[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Finished [0;1;39mLoad Kernel Module pstore_zone[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Finished [0;1;39mLoad Kernel Module ramoops[0m.
         Mounting [0;1;39m/boot/efi[0m...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Finished [0;1;39mLoad Kernel Module chromeos_pstore[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Mounted [0;1;39m/boot/efi[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target [0;1;39mLocal File Systems[0m.
         Starting [0;1;39mLoad AppArmor profiles[0m...
         Starting [0;1;39mSet console font and keymap[0m...
         Starting [0;1;39mClean up any mess left by 0dns-up[0m...
         Starting [0;1;39mTell Plymouth To Write Out Runtime Data[0m...
         Starting [0;1;39mCreate Volatile Files and Directories[0m...
         Starting [0;1;39mUncomplicated firewall[0m...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Finished [0;1;39mSet console font and keymap[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Finished [0;1;39mTell Plymouth To Write Out Runtime Data[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Finished [0;1;39mUncomplicated firewall[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target [0;1;39mPreparation for Network[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Finished [0;1;39mClean up any mess left by 0dns-up[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Finished [0;1;39mCreate Volatile Files and Directories[0m.
         Starting [0;1;39mUserspace Out-Of-Memory (OOM) Killer[0m...
         Starting [0;1;39mNetwork Name Resolution[0m...
         Starting [0;1;39mNetwork Time Synchronization[0m...
         Starting [0;1;39mRecord System Boot/Shutdown in UTMP[0m...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Finished [0;1;39mRecord System Boot/Shutdown in UTMP[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Finished [0;1;39mLoad AppArmor profiles[0m.
         Starting [0;1;39mRaise network interfaces[0m...
         Starting [0;1;39mLoad AppArmor profiles managed internally by snapd[0m...
         Mounting [0;1;39mArbitrary Executable File Formats File System[0m...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mNetwork Time Synchronization[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target [0;1;39mSystem Time Set[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mUserspace Out-Of-Memory (OOM) Killer[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Mounted [0;1;39mArbitrary Executable File Formats File System[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mNetwork Name Resolution[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target [0;1;39mHost and Network Name Lookups[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Finished [0;1;39mLoad AppArmor profiles managed internally by snapd[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target [0;1;39mSystem Initialization[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mACPI Events Check[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mProcess error reports when automatic reporting is enabled (file watch)[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mCUPS Scheduler[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mTrigger anacron every hour[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mProcess error reports when automatic reporting is enabled (timer based)[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mDaily apt download activities[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mDaily apt upgrade and clean activities[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mDaily dpkg database backup timer[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mPeriodic ext4 Online Metadata Check for All Filesystems[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mDiscard unused blocks once a week[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mRefresh fwupd metadata regularly[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mDaily rotation of log files[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mDaily man-db regeneration[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mMessage of the Day[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mClean PHP session files every 30 mins[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mUpdate the plocate database daily[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mDaily Cleanup of Temporary Directories[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mUbuntu Advantage Timer for running repeated jobs[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target [0;1;39mPath Units[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Listening on [0;1;39mACPID Listen Socket[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Listening on [0;1;39mAvahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack Activation Socket[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Listening on [0;1;39mCUPS Scheduler[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Listening on [0;1;39mD-Bus System Message Bus Socket[0m.
         Starting [0;1;39mDocker Socket for the API[0m...
         Starting [0;1;39mSocket activation for snappy daemon[0m...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Listening on [0;1;39mUUID daemon activation socket[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Finished [0;1;39mRaise network interfaces[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Listening on [0;1;39mDocker Socket for the API[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Listening on [0;1;39mSocket activation for snappy daemon[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target [0;1;39mSocket Units[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target [0;1;39mBasic System[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mACPI event daemon[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mRun anacron jobs[0m.
         Starting [0;1;39mLSB: automatic crash report generation[0m...
         Starting [0;1;39mAvahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack[0m...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mD-Bus System Message Bus[0m.
         Starting [0;1;39mNetwork Manager[0m...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mSave initial kernel messages after boot[0m.
         Starting [0;1;39mRemove Stale Online ext4 Metadata Check Snapshots[0m...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target [0;1;39mLogin Prompts[0m.
         Starting [0;1;39mDetect the available GPUs and deal with any system changes[0m...
         Starting [0;1;39mRecord successful boot for GRUB[0m...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mirqbalance daemon[0m.
         Starting [0;1;39mLSB: Start lightdm[0m...
         Starting [0;1;39mInitialize hardware monitoring sensors[0m...
         Starting [0;1;39mDispatcher daemon for systemd-networkd[0m...
         Starting [0;1;39mClean php session files[0m...
         Starting [0;1;39mAuthorization Manager[0m...
         Starting [0;1;39mPower Profiles daemon[0m...
         Starting [0;1;39mSystem Logging Service[0m...
         Starting [0;1;39mSecure Boot updates for DB and DBX[0m...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target [0;1;39mPreparation for Logins[0m.
         Starting [0;1;39mSnap Daemon[0m...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target [0;1;39mUser and Group Name Lookups[0m.
[[0;1;38;5;185mDEPEND[0m] Dependency failed for [0;1;39mSSSD NSS Service responder socket[0m.
[[0;1;38;5;185mDEPEND[0m] Dependency failed for [0;1;39mSSSD AutoFS Service responder socket[0m.
[[0;1;38;5;185mDEPEND[0m] Dependency failed for [0;1;39mSSSD PAC Service responder socket[0m.
[[0;1;38;5;185mDEPEND[0m] Dependency failed for [0;1;39mSSSD PAM Service responder private socket[0m.
[[0;1;38;5;185mDEPEND[0m] Dependency failed for [0;1;39mSSSD PAM Service responder socket[0m.
[[0;1;38;5;185mDEPEND[0m] Dependency failed for [0;1;39mSSSD SSH Service responder socket[0m.
[[0;1;38;5;185mDEPEND[0m] Dependency failed for [0;1;39mSSSD Sudo Service responder socket[0m.
         Starting [0;1;39mAccounts Service[0m...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mRegular background program processing daemon[0m.
         Starting [0;1;39mSwitcheroo Control Proxy service[0m...
         Starting [0;1;39mUser Login Management[0m...
         Starting [0;1;39mDisk Manager[0m...
         Starting [0;1;39mLSB: This services starts and stops the USB Arbitrator.[0m...
         Starting [0;1;39mWPA supplicant[0m...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Finished [0;1;39mRemove Stale Online ext4 Metadata Check Snapshots[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mLSB: Start lightdm[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Finished [0;1;39mInitialize hardware monitoring sensors[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mStart whoopsie on modification of the /var/crash directory[0m.
         Starting [0;1;39mProcess error reports when automatic reporting is enabled[0m...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mLSB: automatic crash report generation[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Finished [0;1;39mRecord successful boot for GRUB[0m.
         Starting [0;1;39mGRUB failed boot detection[0m...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Finished [0;1;39mGRUB failed boot detection[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mSystem Logging Service[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Finished [0;1;39mSecure Boot updates for DB and DBX[0m.
```

But after that, the Ubunto logo appears, and need to wait about 2 minutes.

Here is a critical chain

```
graphical.target @2min 11.767s
└─multi-user.target @2min 11.767s
  └─plymouth-quit-wait.service @41.693s +1min 30.072s
    └─systemd-user-sessions.service @41.368s +303ms
      └─network.target @41.303s
        └─NetworkManager.service @33.878s +7.424s
          └─dbus.service @33.874s
            └─basic.target @33.829s
              └─sockets.target @33.829s
                └─snapd.socket @33.827s +1ms
                  └─sysinit.target @33.732s
                    └─snapd.apparmor.service @31.054s +2.677s
                      └─apparmor.service @29.008s +2.043s
                        └─local-fs.target @28.973s
                          └─run-snapd-ns-snapd\x2ddesktop\x2dintegration.mnt.mount @1min 19.146s
                            └─run-snapd-ns.mount @1min 16.798s
                              └─local-fs-pre.target @9.273s
                                └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service @8.197s +1.075s
                                  └─systemd-sysusers.service @7.069s +1.098s
                                    └─systemd-remount-fs.service @6.971s +95ms
                                      └─systemd-journald.socket @6.715s
                                        └─system.slice @6.674s
                                          └─-.slice @6.674s
```

Can somebody tell me what could be wrong?

If you need more logs, please tell me.

**EDIT:**

Here is a

```
$systemd-analyze blame
1min 30.072s plymouth-quit-wait.service
 57.318s mysql.service
 57.089s docker.service
 35.318s php8.1-fpm.service
 26.226s snapd.service
 25.153s containerd.service
 21.484s systemd-journal-flush.service
 20.393s networkd-dispatcher.service
 15.367s dev-sda2.device
 14.404s dev-loop29.device
 13.890s dev-loop9.device
 13.386s gpu-manager.service
 13.006s vmware-USBArbitrator.service
 12.960s dev-loop0.device
 12.582s udisks2.service
 12.475s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
 12.235s accounts-daemon.service
 12.038s nginx.service
 11.858s dev-loop21.device
 11.781s dev-loop18.device
 11.697s dev-loop32.device
 11.480s dev-loop20.device
 11.452s dev-loop22.device
 11.349s dev-loop26.device
 11.287s dev-loop19.device
 11.266s dev-loop11.device
 11.243s dev-loop25.device
 ...
```

Comment: Related: [How to decrease the boot time](https://askubuntu.com/q/1166486)

Comment: "Desktop"? ... Do you need `mysql` and `docker` and `php8.1-fpm` to automatically run on every boot? They are delaying your boot as well by a great deal.

Comment: @IgorPopov You might want to have a look at this post: [Slow boot issue due to plymouth-quit-wait.service + ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/q/1119167/968501)

Comment: @Raffa Since, I am a PHP backend developer, so yes.

Comment: @Raffa You are right, I meant workstation instead desktop.

Comment: That is understood ... However what I meant is unless this machine is a server, you can disable the automatic startup services `mysql.service`, `docker.service` and `php8.1-fpm.service` to see if your machine boots any faster ... Those services can actually be manually started after login with e.g. `sudo systemctl start mysql.service` ... etc. ... Also, disabling `NetworkManager-wait-online.service` should be totally safe, if not a server, and might greatly shorten boot time in some cases ... Snap mounts are delaying your boot as well but we can't do anything about them, unfortunately.

Comment: https://orangesputnik.org/ubuntu-desktop-optimization/ Read here about plymouth-quit-wait.service And yes do you really need these services mentioned by Raffa every load?