# Slower boot time on newer laptop

Tags: boot

My boot time on my old laptop (asus k501uw) is 19s, but on the new laptop (hp pavilion) is 29s. It is not slow, but I wonder if it is possible to improve it. Thanks

**EDIT:** Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. Plus, screenshots of what systemd-analyze tells me about it.

[image]

[image]

[image]

This one is from the old laptop, that shouldn't boot faster than the newer one, considering that the system, configuration, applications is pretty much the same, but on older hardware.

[image]

**EDIT 2:** If I disable gpu-manager.service (systemctl disable gpu-manager.service), would that be wrong? I rather ask, since I don't know enough.

Comment: You've provided no OS/release details; are we to guess?   Why not provide the text as text in your question; a picture of text (esp. with transparent background) is very difficult to read & I'm just moving on.. others may do the same...

Comment: @guiverc I just edited the post with more information, clearer pictures, and description. Thanks

Comment: There is a post here about that first line in your output: [slow-boot-issue-due-to-plymouth-quit-wait-service-ubuntu-18-04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1119167/slow-boot-issue-due-to-plymouth-quit-wait-service-ubuntu-18-04) (not necessarily going to solve the problem but may provide information.